# Can't use chrome driver for Selenium

Tags: python, google-chrome, python-3.x, selenium, python-3.3

I'm having trouble using the Chrome driver for Selenium. I have the chromedriver downloaded and saved to C:\Chrome:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Chrome/")
```

Using that gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1105, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\service.py", line 63, in start
    self.service_args, env=env, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 817, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\subprocess.py", line 1111, in _execute_child
    raise WindowsError(*e.args)
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Wilson/Dropbox/xxx.py", line 71, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Chrome/")
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\service.py", line 68, in start
    and read up at http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path.                 Please download from http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You should specify the executable file path, not the directory path that contains the executable.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: Worked like a charm for Mac without the .exe estension

Comment: hi there - whats the difference between 



`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Chrome/")`

and this one 

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")`


Note: i work on Win10 - i have issues with the chromedriver too - so i am working on the same things - look forward to hear from you

Comment: @zero, Sorry, I don't have an access to windows 10 machine. Please post a separated question so that others with windows machine can answer you.

Answer (score 36):

**For Linux**

1. Check you have installed latest version of chrome browser-> **"chromium-browser -version"**
2. If not, install latest version of chrome **"sudo apt-get install chromium-browser"**
3. Get the appropriate version of chrome driver from: 
   latest https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing
   older http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html
4. Unzip the chromedriver.zip
5. Move the file to /usr/bin directory **sudo mv chromedriver /usr/bin**
6. Goto /usr/bin directory and you would need to run something like "**chmod a+x chromedriver**" to mark it executable.
7. finally you can execute the code.

   from selenium import webdriver
   driver = webdriver.Chrome()
   driver.get("http://www.google.com")
   display.stop()

Comment: Isn't chromedriver should be put under /usr/local/bin directory in Ubuntu instead of /usr/bin ? please clarify

Comment: @vikramvi it doesn't matter as long as the directory is on your path

Comment: @CoreyGoldberg I will prefer to put under default directory instead of custom directory

Comment: good evening dear Viky - many thanks for the great answer. BTW - one question left: hi there - whats the difference between 



`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Chrome/")`

and this one 

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")`

Note: i work on Win10 - i have issues with the chromedriver too - so i am working on the same things - look forward to hear from you

Comment: before installing latest version of chromium-browser make sure that you have the latest version of  google chrome itself with
>sudo apt install google-chrome-stable

Answer (score 8):

For windows

Download webdriver from:

http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.9/chromedriver_win32.zip

Paste the chromedriver.exe file in  "C:\Python27\Scripts" Folder.

This should work now.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Comment: Wow, I spent hours one this. Can I do that with basically any driver exe?

Comment: Along a go i did that, try out and update me as well :)

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the selected answer (windows style path):

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe")
```

Note the *r* in front of the "C:\Chrome\chromedriver.exe", this makes this string a raw string.

In case you do not want to use a raw string you should escape the slash like so \\, this would become:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\\Chrome\\chromedriver.exe")
```

Or you can replace the \ with a /, you will get this:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Chrome/chromedriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 2):

When you call selenium or any testing automation library, you would need to add this the code here is in `Python` but this can be done in `Java` and `Ruby` as well.

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.binary_location = '/usr/bin/chromium-browser'
#All the arguments added for chromium to work on selenium
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox") #This make Chromium reachable
options.add_argument("--no-default-browser-check") #Overrides default choices
options.add_argument("--no-first-run")
options.add_argument("--disable-default-apps") 
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/travis/virtualenv/python2.7.9/chromedriver',chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Why the `--no-sandbox`?

Answer (score 2):

For Debian/Ubuntu - it works:

install Google Chrome for Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt-get install libxss1 libappindicator1 libindicator7
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-
stable_current_amd64.deb

sudo dpkg -i google-chrome*.deb
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Install ChromeDriver:

```
wget -N http://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/2.26/chromedriver_linux64.zip
unzip chromedriver_linux64.zip
chmod +x chromedriver

sudo mv -f chromedriver /usr/local/share/chromedriver
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
sudo ln -s /usr/local/share/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
```

Install Selenium:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

Selenium in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in/')
```

Comment: Note: Can use `apt` instead of `apt-get` in more recent versions of ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

All you need to do is Paste the **Chromedriver.exe** in *python36-32* folder.And you can use It Simply like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

No need to paste path again and again.

***OR***
You can Use:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:/Chrome/chromedriver.exe")
```

Answer (score 0):

## Chrome

```
import os   
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = "C://chromedriver.exe"                                                                     
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver                      
driver =webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
chromedriver = "C:\Drivers\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver =webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("https://www.facebook.com")
print(driver.title)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Can you add some further information as to how this helps solve the initial question?

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 0):

**For Windows with virtual workspace**

First, check your browser version: go to 3 dons most right corner of the chrome browser and click it, then, --> Help-->About Google Chrome

once you identify our browser version, we have to download and install chrome drive from [this link](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads)

extract the zip folder and past chromedriver.exe file in 
 C:\Users\name\virtual_workspace\Scripts

```
from selenium import webdriver
wbdriver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't need path to drive file:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

    driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Answer (score -3):

Just place the chromedriver.exe in your python folder (in my case: C:\Python27) and use the below mentioned code it will work for you guys

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("URL")
```