# Using chromedriver with selenium/python/ubuntu

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to execute some tests using chromedriver and have tried using the following methods to start chromedriver.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

and

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

and

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver

chromedriver = "/usr/local/bin/chromedriver"
os.environ["webdriver.chrome.driver"] = chromedriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
driver.get("http://stackoverflow.com")
```

But none of these seems to help and the error is : `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path.`

I have checked multiple times and `chromedriver` is present in location `/usr/local/bin`.

Still my scripts are not working. Could any body pls help.

My google-chrome location is : /usr/bin/google-chrome

Comment: Make sure the chromedriver binary is available in the provided path and not the directory which contains chromedriver.exe

Comment: This is the location of binary, not the directory. @Amith

Comment: i have already answered it in another question [selenium/python/ubuntu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130109/cant-use-chrome-driver-for-selenium/44039546#44039546)

Comment: For Debian/Ubuntu - it works:
see the below link [chrome-webdriver for selenium/python/ubuntu ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22130109/cant-use-chrome-driver-for-selenium/44039546#44039546)

Comment: @ShintoJoseph, so it doesn't respect PATH in any way?

Answer (score 83):

Following the suggestion from https://askubuntu.com/questions/539498/where-does-chromedriver-install-to I was able to make it work like this:

1. Installed the chromium-chromedriver:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install chromium-chromedriver
   ```
2. Adding the path to the selenium line:

   ```
   driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver")
   ```

Note that this opens Chromium and not Chrome. Hope it was helpful.

Comment: Worked for me perfectly

Comment: I've tried plenty of advices (e.g. setting --no-sandbox, --disable-dev-shm-usage, using WebDriver Manager, I even snap-aliased chromium to google-chrome). This worked even with chromium version 102.x.y.

Answer (score 12):

I have solved the issue in the following way:

1. Open a terminal and type `whereis chromedriver`. In my case, I had the following output:

   `chromedriver: /usr/local/bin/chromedriver`
2. Copy that path and edit your Webdriver instance like:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

That should be enough!

Answer (score 5):

The following should normally work:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
```

Note that in your question there was no preceding '/' in the path.

Additionally, make sure that the chromedriver executable located in /usr/local/bin/ has appropriate file permissions, i.e. that it can be executed:

```
> chmod 777 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

Comment: I have changed chmod to 777 and have already used the preceeding '/' [edited]. Still the same error. @Tytus

Comment: This approach worked for me. All the above approaches did not work on their own....I first needed to change permissions and then `executable_path` worked.

Answer (score 2):

As the message says: ChromeDriver executable needs to be available in the path.

So is it in the path? What is the output of:

```
$ cd
$ chromedriver --version
```

If you don’t see the version, `chromedriver` is definitively not in the PATH.

I don’t tell webdriver where to find `chromedriver` otherwise. – I use the Ubuntu package “chromium-chromedriver”, but it drops the binary in `/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver`, which is not in my PATH. So I put a soft link in `/usr/bin`.

Answer (score 2):

It is enough to point out to the Chrome Browser driver on your machine.
If you already have Chromium browser installed, then search for the driver:

```
sudo find / -type f -name chromedriver
```

then select the driver corresponding to your browser.

PS: for me it was

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/snap/chromium/1827/usr/lib/chromium-browser/chromedriver')
```

Answer (score 1):

For `Mac` users:

1. `brew install chromedriver`.
2. After installation `==> Linking Binary 'chromedriver' to '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'` will popup.
3. From now on, you **should** be able refer to `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` in the code.
4. You might face [Selenium Python: No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver' but it exists and is added to path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55111180/selenium-python-no-such-file-or-directory-usr-local-bin-chromedriver-but-it) and/or [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path). It's because `brew install cask` is required as well, as explained in https://www.kenst.com/2015/03/installing-chromedriver-on-mac-osx/.
5. Again an error `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/usr/local/bin/chromedriver'`? Try `brew reinstall chromedriver` and it was the first time `brew reinstall chromedriver` (got from [Using Selenium on Mac Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38081021/using-selenium-on-mac-chrome)) returned something different than `chromedriver not found`. Namely, `/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` :)
6. The last issue I was facing was `“chromedriver” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified.` popup whenever I've tried to run the script. `cd /usr/local/bin`, then `xattr -d com.apple.quarantine chromedriver` (credits: [MacOS Catalina(v 10.15.3): Error: “chromedriver” cannot be opened because the developer cannot be verified. Unable to launch the chrome browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60362018/macos-catalinav-10-15-3-error-chromedriver-cannot-be-opened-because-the-de)) solves the problem, and the `ChromeDriver` finally ran.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have not complete installing the chrome driver. I suggest you to install this with apt, Because apt installs all dependencies itself.
The other answers are true; but in the last versions which installed "chromium-browser". but now this name is changed to "chromium-driver".  so you shoulde install this:

```
apt-get install chromium-driver
```

this driver will be installed in /usr/bin and this name will be "chromedriver"
so for import path to selenium use this path: /usr/bin/chromedriver:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/chromedriver')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure the standalone ChromeDriver binary is either in your path or available in the webdriver.chrome.driver environment variable and then try to use absolute path to that binary.
Below is the code for java -

```
    File chromeDriver = new File("/usr/bin/chromedriver");
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", chromeDriver.getAbsolutePath());
    driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the binary location as argument to it and not just the directory conatining it. So if it lies in /usr/bin directory, then run below command:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver")
```

This worked for me in ubuntu and adding path to bashrc is not working. Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

hope this will be useful for some who did like me.
For my case i left preceding slash in the path did "home/user/chromedriver" instead of "/home/user/chromedriver"