# Activating a button within a Python spider program

Tags: python, scrapy

I am absolutely stuck on this one.  I am scraping restaurant URLs from a webpage and there is a button at the bottom to reveal more restaurants.  The website button code is below (i believe):

```
<div id="restsPages">
<a class="next" data-url="https://hungryhouse.co.uk/takeaways/aberdeen-bridge-of-dee-ab10">Show more</a>
<a class="back">Back to top</a>
</div>
```

It is the "Show more" button i am trying to activate.  The url within the "data-url" does not reveal more of the page.

It all seems a bit odd on what do do to activate the button from within the python spider?

The code i am trying to use to make this work is:

```
import scrapy

from hungryhouse.items import HungryhouseItem
from selenium import webdriver  

class HungryhouseSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "hungryhouse"
    allowed_domains = ["hungryhouse.co.uk"]
    start_urls = ["https://hungryhouse.co.uk/takeaways/westhill-ab10",
                      ]
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()

    def parse(self,response):
        self.driver.get(response.url)

        while True:
            next =self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="restsPages"]/a[@class="next"]')
            try:
                next.click()
            except:
                break
        self.driver.close()

.... rest of the code follows
```

The error i get is: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Comment: This was resolved http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699416/pressing-a-button-within-python-code with reference to the answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved at [Pressing a button within python code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40699416/pressing-a-button-within-python-code) with reference to the answer at [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

But specifically

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

needed to change to

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/andrew/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
```

in my case.

i.e. I needed to add the path to chromedriver.exe.