# selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH error with Headless Chrome

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, headless, google-chrome-headless

when i run my script , i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ishaq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\ishaq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\ishaq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\subprocess.py", line 992, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/ishaq/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python36/headless.py", line 9, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("chromedriver"),   chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "C:\Users\ishaq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 62, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\ishaq\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

here is my script

```
import os  
from selenium import webdriver  
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys  
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 

chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
chrome_options.binary_location = 
r'C:\Users\ishaq\Desktop\chrome\chromedriver.exe'    
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.abspath("chromedriver"),   
chrome_options=chrome_options)  
driver.get("http://www.duo.com") 

magnifying_glass = driver.find_element_by_id("js-open-icon")  
if magnifying_glass.is_displayed():  
  magnifying_glass.click()  
else:  
  menu_button = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".menu-trigger.local")  
  menu_button.click() 

search_field = driver.find_element_by_id("site-search")  
search_field.clear()  
search_field.send_keys("Olabode")  
search_field.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)  
assert "Looking Back at Android Security in 2016" in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Comment: Before posting a question you should spend some time reading the error messages and trying to understand what the errors are. Then you should spend some time googling the errors so you can better understand what the errors mean and how people have solved them. This is a common error and there's already a solution if you'd spent the time to look for it.

Comment: @JeffC actually i was confused in os.path and binary.location . i search alot about it and didnt find a solution thats why i posted this question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If we analyze the logs it seems the main issue is with in *`start os.path.basename(self.path)`* and subsequent error message:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH
```

So it's clear from the error that the Python client was unable to locate the *chromedriver* executable binary.

You need to take care of a couple of things as follows:

1. *`chrome_options.binary_location`* : The parameter points to the chrome.exe not the chromedriver.exe
2. *`os.path.abspath("chromedriver")`* will pick up the file path of chromedriver but won't append chromedriver.exe at the end.
3. Here is the sample code on my [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8) system to start [google-chrome-headless](/questions/tagged/google-chrome-headless):

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver  
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 

   chrome_options = Options()  
   chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')  
   driver.get("http://www.duo.com") 
   print("Chrome Browser Initialized in Headless Mode")
   driver.quit()
   print("Driver Exited")
   ```

Comment: Alternatively, you can also try [**`Mozilla Firefox in Headless Mode`**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPS89xCgNhk&t=528s)

Comment: my script is working great in local, but i want to run my script remotely , i dont want to run my machine all day