# Getting the following error when trying to open web page with Selenium WebDriver in python 3.6?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, python-3.6, python-webbrowser

When I try to execute this code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver= webdriver.Firefox("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox")
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

I get the following error :

```
C:\Users\vipul\PycharmProjects\newproject\venv\Scripts\python.exe "C:/Users/vipul/PycharmProjects/newproject/Web Scraping.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vipul\PycharmProjects\newproject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 74, in start
    stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file)
  File "C:\Users\vipul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\Users\vipul\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\subprocess.py", line 997, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/vipul/PycharmProjects/newproject/Web Scraping.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver= webdriver.Firefox("C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox")
  File "C:\Users\vipul\PycharmProjects\newproject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\vipul\PycharmProjects\newproject\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Push your code trials.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [chrome headless browswer selenium python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085270/chrome-headless-browswer-selenium-python/46089751#46089751)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have faced the same issue before a week ago, 
I was using Python 2.7 and the latest version of web driver of Chrome, 
Then I passed geckodriver file path like,

```
driver= webdriver.Firefox("c://your-path")
```

This fixed my issue, I hoped for your too.

Comment: Path opens the browser but does not opens the webpage plz help

Comment: Is webpage showing broken error? or any other error you are facing?

Answer (score 0):

Download geckodriver.exe to a particular folder/directory(eg. c:\drivers) then set the driver path.

Try any one of the following ways.

1. Pass driver path as argument.

   ```
   driver= webdriver.Firefox("c:\drivers\geckodriver.exe")
   driver.get("http://google.com")
   ```
2. Set driver path using enviornment.

   ```
   import os
   os.environ['webdriver.gecko.driver'] ="c:\drivers\geckodriver.exe"
   driver.get("http://google.com")
   ```

Note: if you are keeping gecko driver exe file in local folder where the script is there. then no need to set or pass the driver path.