# Error in creating a firefox session in selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, firefox, webautomation

I'm new to selenium library, please help me solve this error to start a firefox session using selenium.

This is my code so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

# create a new Firefox session
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
```

and the error occurring is

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "C:\Users\yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
> line 74, in start stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file) File
> "C:\Users\yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 707, in __init__restore_signals, start_new_session) File
> "C:\Users\yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-2\lib\subprocess.py",
> line 990, in _execute_child startupinfo) FileNotFoundError: [WinError
> 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last): File
> "A:\python\webscraping\seltry.py", line 5, in  driver =
> webdriver.Firefox() File
> "C:\Users\yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py",
> line 148, in **init**        self.service.start() File
> "C:\Users\yash\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py",
> line 81, in start os.path.basename(self.path),
> self.start_error_message)
> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver'
> executable needs to be in PATH.

please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH error with chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085270/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executabl)

Answer (score 0):

The error: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.` pretty much explains this. You can follow this tutorial [Selenium using Python - Geckodriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40208051/selenium-using-python-geckodriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)

And please research your question before asking as I think this could be considered a dublicate by some.

Comment: This IS a duplicate and should be marked as such instead of answering it so we don't end up with lots of dups and they will get cleaned up.