# Not loading firefox on selenium webdriver

Tags: linux, selenium, ubuntu

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 148, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 81, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Everything is installed. When i type firefox in terminal, it perfectly opens firefox browser. Help me!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH error with chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085270/chrome-headless-browswer-selenium-python/46089751#46089751)

Comment: Please paste your code snippet that you tried so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FirefoxDriver for Selenium has been discontinued. You must use MarionetteDriver/geckodriver.