# Selenium: How to use Headless Chrome on AWS?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome-headless

Today I saw the message `UserWarning: Selenium support for PhantomJS has been deprecated, please use headless versions of Chrome or Firefox instead`.

I am willing to for for Chrome route. How do I install on AWS and run it on my remote AWS instance?

I will be using `selenium` in Python.

Comment: just add `chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")` or use docker image for chrome-standalone

Comment: See the discussion https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085270/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executabl/46089751#46089751

Comment: @DebanjanB don't find any trace of installing on AWS.

Comment: Well, your question seems unclear. 1) Heading speaks about _Use Headless Chrome on AWS_. 2) Body speaks about _install on AWS_ 3) Tag on _selenium_ . What is your exact question?

Answer (score 15):

Create a new EC2 instance.

SSH log into the machine.

Install python, selenium, chromedriver, chromium, and python packages what you need.

```
sudo apt install chromium-chromedriver
```

Copy your python script to the machine.

Edit the script and add an chromeoption.

```
import selenium as se

options = se.webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('headless')

driver = se.webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

Done!

Comment: I see this when I do that: `selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

Comment: @EdSummers Find chromedriver executable path and add the path into your PATH environment variable.

Comment: @Leon how to do that?

Comment: Here is a good article about path: [How to set your $PATH variable in Linux](https://opensource.com/article/17/6/set-path-linux)

Answer (score 4):

I prefer to use Firefox so this is my Python3 implementation

```
def createHeadlessFirefoxBrowser():
     options = webdriver.FirefoxOptions()
     options.add_argument('--headless')
     return webdriver.Firefox(options=options)

browser = createHeadlessFirefoxBrowser()
```

Comment: how did you get the driver?