# WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. - selenium

Tags: linux, selenium, selenium-webdriver, path, executable

Before you let me know that this is a duplicate, the issue I am facing is that I am running my python code using a jupyter-notebook via an Ubuntu subsystem on Windows.

I have made sure that the path to the folder on Windows where chromedriver is located is correct. However, I am still getting the same error. Further, I am unable to see where my files from the Ubuntu subsystem are (ie, I can't find a folder on Windows with those files).

Anyway in which I can correct this? such as editing the `~/.bashrc` file on Ubuntu?

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/vr235/Downloads/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe")
```

Error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

*EDIT:*

While a solution was pointed by user DebanjanB and marked as duplicate, I tried the user's suggestion but got the same error.

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options 

chrome_options = Options()  
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")  
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\vr235\Downloads\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe')  
browser.get("https://www.sciencedirect.com/")
```

Error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'C:\Users\vr235\Downloads\chromedriver\chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH error with chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085270/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executabl)

Comment: Tried your solution. It still didn't work. @DebanjanB

Answer (score 2):

In case one is using a WSL, one can identify the path where the Chromedriver is present by viewing the `mnt` folder on WSL.

For instance: My chromedriver path was in the Downloads folder in C:/ drive

`Path : /mnt/c/vr235/Users/Downloads/chromedriver.exe`

Once you add the same, the above lines of code work perfectly.