# Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH while executing python selenium on web server

Tags: php, python, web-services, selenium, webserver

I have a python script for scraping with selenium. Everything is going well on my local laptop.
But when I put this python file on the web server, it always had errors about selenium and now I can't execute successfully owing to

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_availability.py", line 32, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: 
  Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

But I put the `chromedriver` in the same location as where `chromedriver` is on my local laptop on the web server. And the error appears.
I tried many methods but this error still there.

I put `chromedriver` into `/usr/local/bin` on the web server
My question is different from the 
[selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH error with Headless Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085270/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executabl)
Since I already used the method from the accepted acswer, but there still show the error

I need to run my python file on the web server. Below is my codes:

```
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = "/home/animalsp/public_html/maps/maps2/chromedriver"
WINDOW_SIZE ="1920,1080"
chrome_options = Options() 
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, chrome_options=chrome_options)
driver.get("https://na.chargepoint.com/charge_point")
```

And I even tried it with Firefox. Below is my codes with Firefox:

```
FIREFOXDRIVER_PATH ="/home/animalsp/public_html/maps/maps2/geckodriver"
WINDOW_SIZE ="1920,1080"
firefox_options = Options() 
firefox_options.add_argument("--headless")
firefox_options.add_argument("--window-size=%s" % WINDOW_SIZE)

driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=FIREFOXDRIVER_PATH, firefox_options=firefox_options)
driver.get("https://na.chargepoint.com/charge_point")
```

Could someone help me with this?
Any response will be appreciated!

> Selenium 3.12.0
>
> python 3.6.5
>
> Chrome 66.0
>
> Chromedriver 2.3.8
>
> Firefox 60
>
> geckodriver v0.20.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH error with Headless Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085270/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executabl)

Comment: PHP tag doesn't seem necessary given the context.

Comment: @DebanjanB Sorry we have different problems

Comment: @DylanMoore my final propose is executing python file by php, but now I can't run my py file in the webserver

Answer (score 2):

You need to put your **chromedriver** executable file in same directory where you run your script and change your chrome_path to this:

```
import os
chrome_path = os.path.realpath('chromedriver')
```