# Selenium Chrome driver showing path not specified

Tags: python, selenium

while running any selenium code it shows this
I have even added chromedriver.exe to my directory but still this error comes up

```
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Programming\Python\Projects\_Acoustify_\Scrapping bots\amazon_bot_2.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: What directory is `chromedriver.exe` in? It has to be on your PATH

Comment: How did you initialize the driver ?

Comment: @chemicalwill Thank you so much earlier the chromedriver was in my project directory but not in the directory which I am working in, Thank you so much :)

Comment: @VanshKhera I'm glad to hear it! You can keep chromedriver in your directory, you just have to pass it to `webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH error with Headless Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46085270/selenium-common-exceptions-webdriverexception-message-chromedriver-executabl)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the last line of the error, you have to have `chromedriver` in PATH.

If you want to keep it in your project directory, add the path for `chromedriver` to your `webdriver` call:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
```