# Error in running Headless Chrome with Selenium and Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, google-chrome-headless

I have been trying to run a very basic script in Python 3.6 which uses Selenium & chromedriver-2.42.

Here is the script:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import os

ch = os.getcwd() + '\\chromedriver'
options = Options()
options.set_headless(headless=True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=ch)
driver.get("http://google.com/")
driver.get_screenshot_as_file('capture.png')
driver.quit()
```

While running it, I get the following error:

[image: Error]

I am using Windows 7 x64.

It'll be a great help if anyone could guide me to solve this error.
Thank you!

Comment: Try to give complete path of chromedriver.exe in place of chromedriver

Comment: Are you sure it's actually erring? Those could just be extra scruff from chromedriver.

Comment: @thebadguy no results

Comment: @LucasTierney It is more like an infinite loop, becuase I have placed a "quit()" function there so the command window should be closed after a while, but that is not happening, the command window stays up and shows this.

Comment: One thing I have noticed, the last line starting with "DevTools.." also appears when I run the script without "--headless" option.

Comment: can you try https://stackoverflow.com/a/46967289/2425654 and pass only options

Comment: @thebadguy Thank You, but adding the "--no-sandbox" option worked!