# How to add Chromedriver to PATH in linux?

Tags: linux, google-chrome, selenium

Trying to use Selenium with Chrome in a python script.

I get the following error:

```
WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

I know the location of the chromedriver executable. 
How do I add it to the PATH?

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can specify the absolute path to your chrome driver in your script as such:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/driver/chromedriver')
```

Or you can add the path to your webdriver in the `PATH` system variable as so:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/driver/chrome-driver
```

You may add the above line to your `/home/<user>/.profile` file to make it permanent.

Tested on Ubuntu 17.10 running Python 2.7.14

Hope this helps!

Comment: Append a directory to the existing PATH:
`export PATH=/usr/local/path/example:$PATH`
     To list the current PATH, issue command:
`echo $PATH`

Answer (score 17):

The solution posted by @AnythingIsFine is indeed correct.

However in my case my pytest was still unable to find the chromedriver (despite it was correctly added to the PATH and from the terminal I could execute it).

So I've solved by adding an alias of the `chromedriver` in the `/usr/bin` directory:

```
sudo ln -s /path/to/chromedriver /usr/bin
```

Comment: first answer did not take effect... this one did, not sure if it was the combination of both! thanks man!

Comment: ```ln -s `which chromedriver` /usr/bin``` LazyWay ..

Answer (score 5):

Move Chromedriver to path with:

```
sudo mv -f ~/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/chromedriver
```

`/usr/local/bin/chromedriver` is path.

Answer (score 0):

For selenium framework (python or java), Browser driver(chrome/firefox/  etc.) should be saved on the Path " /usr/local/bin/chromedriver  & /usr/bin/chromedriver"

For Chrome Driver Link : https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads
go to the link and download the chrome driver for corresponding OS.

Linux:
Open the terminal on the Saved/downloaded directory then enter the command

"sudo mv /path/to/chromedriver /usr/bin"
"sudo mv /path/to/chromedriver /usr/local/bin"

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way would be to download the `Google Chrome Driver` you prefer and drop in `/usr/share/bin` directory in `Linux`.

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads (to download Chrome Driver needed)

```
sudo mv -v <location_downloaded_chromedriver>/chromedriver /usr/local/bin/.
```

To make sure `Chrome Driver` is properly working, you may check the version you just installed as below:

```
/usr/local/bin/chromedriver -v  #prints you the installed version
```