# Selenium - problem with executable_path on linux mint

Tags: python, selenium, pycharm

I have problem with run the selenium on Pycharm in linux mint.
I add (which chromedriver --> /usr/bin/chromedriver ) the correct path and selenium show error.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import os

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/bin/chromedriver')
driver.get("https://google.com")

driver.close()
```

Error:

````
File "/var/data/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. 
Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home```
````

Comment: Try adding the path of ChromeDriver to PATH system variable. Please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213384/how-to-add-chromedriver-to-path-in-linux.

Comment: @NafeezQuraishi unfortunately, don't work :(

Comment: May be you want to double check if chromedriver executable indeed exists in the path, also may be try to copy the driver to some other location e.g. /data as there might be permission issues to the location you used. Also, there are several answers already available to the same issue as marked in the Question now, please go through them.

Comment: I reinstall system and start working, i think i have problem with some binded in the past path to google-chrome.