# Problem when try to run Selenium Test on Ubuntu

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver

I trying to run easy selenium test under Ubuntu

```
@Test
public void openGoogle() {
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://google.com");
    driver.quit();
}
```

but every single time I run it I am getting that error message:

```
      com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
        java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)V
            at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.findExecutable(DriverService.java:125)
            at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService.access$000(ChromeDriverService.java:35)
            at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriverService$Builder.findDefaultExecutable(ChromeDriverService.java:159)
            ...
```

I have tried to change my build.gradle but It does not work.
Anyone meet same the problem when running Selenium tests?

Answer (score 1):

Selenium can't find driver executable. You need to set path.

[Check here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213384/how-to-add-chromedriver-to-path-in-linux)

https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3880