# cannot call selenium-webdriver in linux

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I'm new at selenium, saw some tutorials but having problems using it.

I have 2 browsers installed and hoping not having to install another to use selenium.

> Opera: Version:96.0.4693.50; System:Linux Mint 20 (x86_64; MATE); Chromium version:110.0.5481.178

> Chromium: Versión 110.0.5481.100 (Build oficial) for Linux Mint (64 bits)

I've searched the web driver for both and the best I could find was:

ChromeDriver 110.0.5481.77 but it's version does not match the chromium one.

I tried :

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome('chromedriver_linux64_114/chromedriver')
```

and get the error `Incompatible release of chromedriver (version 110.0.5481.100) detected in PATH: /usr/bin/chromedriver`

as I understand the version I've downloaded is not compatible, but it was the highest `110` one in chromedriver page (also tried with one `114`... the latest one)

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the system we have to choose for the chrome drivers, and I'm hoping you are following the best practice and tried downloading the latest [Linux Chrome driver](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=114.0.5735.16/) on Linux based system.

Now, verify the location where it is installed and its known to `PATH` under linux source variables. You can also check this for env setup for Linux ([How to add Chromedriver to PATH in linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48213384/how-to-add-chromedriver-to-path-in-linux))

Moreover, you can check the similar threads here which explains more on Windows/MacOS/Linux based systems to set env var for locating ChromeDrivers --> [selenium - chromedriver executable needs to be in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40555930/selenium-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-in-path)