# WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH while setting UserAgent through Selenium Chromedriver python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm a newbie in webscraping, I'm trying to modify my user agent using these lines :

```
from selenium import webdriver
chrome_path = r'C:\Users\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe'   
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_path)
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```

The path in environment variable is ok but I keep having this error message:

```
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in startstdin=PIPE)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py",line 709, in __init__restore_signals, start_new_session)
File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\subprocess.py",line 997, in _execute_child startupinfo).
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\safia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Test 3- User Agent.py", line 9, in <module>
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
File "C:\Users\safia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
self.service.start()
File "C:\Users\safia\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Can you please help me fix this issue?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This error message...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH
```

...implies that the *ChromeDriver* was not found within the locations specified within **PATH** variable within **Environment Variables**.

### Solution

You need to pass the *Key* **executable_path** along with the *Value* referring to the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* along with the *ChromeOptions* object as an argument while initializing the *WebDriver* and *WebBrowser* as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get('https://www.google.co.in')
```

Comment: Thank you very much DebanjanB