# How to close tab with selenium on macos with chrome driver?

Tags: macos, python-2.7, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

My code

```
from selenium import webdriver
dr = webdriver.Chrome()
dr.close()
```

I got this error

> selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you what is wrong: the `chromedriver` program is not found in your executable path (stored in the environment as `$PATH`).

You can tell what the current path is using something like this:

```
import os
print os.environ['PATH']
```

Once you know the path, you can install `chromedriver` into one of the directories in the path.

Answer (score 0):

The correct solution would be to just add the path of your chrome driver. The best way to do that is just have the chrome driver in the same directory as you are probably going to be updating it a lot since google is still working on it.

Comment: is it possible to make it an relative path it didn't work for me when i put my relative path