# catch Email box in login window with selenium (python)

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

URL: https://www.omgeo.com/login
I want to grab the box for Email in this case.

I tried

```
tem = driver.find_element_by_id('user')
tem = driver.find_element_by_name('user')
tem = driver.find_element_by_class_name('ie-background background')
tem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//input[@id="user"]')
```

Selenium reports the same kind of error: Unable to locate the element.

If I click  inspection, I can find HTML code

```
<input type="text" name="user" id="user" size="30" class="ie-background background" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off">
```

However, It will give me a different HTML code when I click view source code which simply does have that piece of HTML code, I guess that's probably why selenium cannot grab the Email box.

Comment: Share the html since I don't want to visit that page.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch to the iframe that contains the form. Here is the code

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import  By


browser = webdriver.Chrome("C:\Py\pythonv4\chrome\chromedriver_2.42.exe")
browser.get('https://www.omgeo.com/login')
browser.switch_to.frame(0)
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(
  EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "user"))
) 
browser.find_element_by_id('user').send_keys("test")
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me that the sign-in form is not rendered during the page load, it appears afterwards. 
Did you try waiting for the "email" element to be rendered?

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

tem = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "email"))
    )
```

The above code will wait for the element to be located in the page, or 10 seconds (whatever happens first).

Comment: Thanks, but I think that is not the issue  <br>  <br>

Comment: @ SebaGra Thanks, I tried the code above. Selenium reported   
    "selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message:"                                                
  Even after ten or twenty seconds, When you click view inspection and view source code, It will still give you two different version HTML code that                                           
    <input type="text" name="user" id="user" size="30" class="ie-background background" tabindex="1" autocomplete="off">                                                             is not in the version "view source code" .

Answer (score 0):

While inspecting the element, I see the element located inside iframe. For frame case as others said,we need switch to the frame before interacting any element inside it.

Also we need to switch back to main content to continue intarcting element in main html.

Mostly the content inside iframe will take time to load. So we need wait for the frame load and switch to it.

For your case, the below code works for me,

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get('https://www.omgeo.com/login')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'iframe[src$=login]')))
driver.find_element_by_id('user').send_keys("emailid")
```

After doing login operation, to interact with main html dom. You need to switch back with below lines.

```py
browser.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

**Note:** *In the above example, I have used webdriver manager to install chrome driver binary automatically. Refer [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path/52878725#52878725) for details*