# How do I interact with a website's interface and how do I call a program in Python?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time

url = 'https://protonmail.com'

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/C:\Users\Usr1\Downloads\chromedriver_win32')
driver.get(url)
```

This program is supposed to open a chrome tab with ProtonMail in it when ran. Instead I receive the error:

```
 SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
 in position 3-4: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

I looked up the error and found no solution. As I am new to python could I get some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:
(1. removed first slash 2. changed other slashes direction 3. added chromeDriver.exe at the end)

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/Users/Usr1/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe')
```

[similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)