# Unable to run the webdriver.chrome() due to error "WebDriverException: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH."

Tags: python, selenium, bots

I was trying to implement a simple bot in python which increases Instagram followers. This is what I was trying-> https://towardsdatascience.com/increase-your-instagram-followers-with-a-simple-python-bot-fde048dce20d
During the process, I installed chromedriver as specified in the above-mentioned post and included the path of it in the webdriver.chrome but I am getting an error stating "**WebDriverException: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home**"

I tried everything which was mentioned in this StackOverflow post ->[Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path) but to no avail. Kindly find my code below and help me sort this error. Thanks in advance

```
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from time import sleep, strftime
from random import randint

#driver=webdriver.Chrome("C:/Users/Users/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")chromedriver_path="C:/Users/Users/Downloads/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe" 

webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = chromedriver_path)

sleep(2)
webdriver.get('https://www.instagram.com/accounts/login/?source=auth_switcher')
sleep(3)
```

Comment: Just add the directory where chromedriver is to the `path` or provide the binary location directly, i.e.: `chrome(path)`

Comment: @PedroLobito Thanks for the reply. I tried that too but didn't help. I got the same error.

Comment: just drop the chromedriver in your python folder, that should be in the path

Comment: @SuperStew Thanks for the reply. I tried but I am getting another new error. 
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)

    SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
    from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 
    'context': {"auxData": 
 {"frameId":"F113CD1D503243A67C09C6D098C1B2BE","isDefault":true,"type":"default"},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)"

Comment: `webdriver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "c:\\path\\chromedriver.exe")` should do it.

Comment: @PedroLobito, Thank you, I tried as you mentioned but I am getting the following error-    SessionNotCreatedException: session not created exception
from unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"28EEEF5294EC948DE015920FEBCFFA5A","isDefault":true,"type":"default"},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.15.322448 (52179c1b310fec1797c81ea9a20326839860b7d3),platform=Windows NT 10.0 x86_64)

Comment: Get the latest driver : https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads

Comment: @PedroLobito, It worked! Thank you so much