# While executing the below script I get the error "'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH"

Tags: python, selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver  
driver = webdriver.Chrome()  
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    r'C:\Users\New User prof\Downloads\chromedriver_win32.zip\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get(
    "https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/url-removal?hl=en&siteUrl=https://www.greatbuyz.com/&mesd=AB9YKzIL4DBt4yX8SVayjC2kUq8yeXctK_u2WGH4KlESTcjXkcOsdBvVP7TnX4S4bBF4PADFQzZAxIqcxMiVerW67kTw-UGIWjHVftlzX5DNcJjm3Uz5wBpWxkDYY7IIFlVMdiEvTsAG_GwgA_DqO7Exg5w80HGHX_lk4okr-Ay7vrCG63zKVLrMGmyNMUPGEESjX2rJF-Xx&authuser=2")

driver.find_element_by_xpath(
    "//button[@class='goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-button-standard']").click()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/pythonnk/my_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 76, in start
    stdin=PIPE)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/subprocess.py", line 1344, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver': 'chromedriver'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bot.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "/root/pythonnk/my_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/root/pythonnk/my_env/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Comment: Is that a zip file `\chromedriver_win32.zip\chromedriver.exe` ? I don't know if that is the correct way to address it. Maybe you need to extract it first?

Comment: In error log, `Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

Comment: Now i changed it to extracted file, but still its not working.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverfloe Naveen. Please look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path

Answer (score 0):

I am not cent percent sure this is the problem. If there are spaces in your path, sometimes the path is not recognized in windows. You can try adding additional double quotes around your path like this.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    r'"C:\Users\New User prof\Downloads\chromedriver_win32.zip\chromedriver.exe"')
```

I can't confirm weather it needs to be extracted. I am not using windows right now so can't test.

Comment: thats not going to help

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you extract the zip file before you use it and provide that extracted file path.
2. Use forward slash while giving the path.
3. Try the code below

   ```
   from selenium import webdriver 
   driver = webdriver.Chrome(
      'C:/Users/New User prof/Downloads/chromedriver_win32.zip/chromedriver.exe')
   driver.get("URL")
   driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@class='goog-inline-block jfk-button jfk-  button-standard']").click()
   ```

Comment: And one thing i noticed is you have written "r" in  the begining of the path