# Extracting data from website using Beautifulsoup

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the model name and any other detail about the models. When i try to fetch text then i can't find anything special which i can use to fetch data.

Anyone know how to fetch data from these urls?

https://www.audi.de/de/brand/de.html

or https://www.opel.de/auswahlhilfe/modelle.html

I would like to get the list of models and any property which is available like price.

So far i am trying to use this:

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import pandas as pd
    from urllib.request import urlopen

    url = "https://www.opel.de/auswahlhilfe/modelle.html"
    html = urlopen(url)
    text = soup.get_text()
```

But i am not getting anything useful.. Any expert here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to Network Tab you will get The below link which returns value in json format.
You don't need selenium to do that.

```
https://www.opel.de/apps/atomic/getVehicleTeasers.path=L2NvbnRlbnQvb3BlbC93b3JsZHdpZGUvZ2VybWFueS9kZS9pbmRleC9iYXNlYmFsbC1jYXJkcy9iYmMtY29sbGVjdGlvbnMvdmVoaWNsZXMtb25seS1jb2xsZWN0aW9uPuGlIfE.feefoEnabled=false.expandingMenuEnabled=false.json
```

Try below code.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
url='https://www.opel.de/apps/atomic/getVehicleTeasers.path=L2NvbnRlbnQvb3BlbC93b3JsZHdpZGUvZ2VybWFueS9kZS9pbmRleC9iYXNlYmFsbC1jYXJkcy9iYmMtY29sbGVjdGlvbnMvdmVoaWNsZXMtb25seS1jb2xsZWN0aW9uPuGlIfE.feefoEnabled=false.expandingMenuEnabled=false.json'
rs=requests.get(url).json()
html=''.join(rs['bbcTeaser'])
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html.parser')
car_name=[]
car_price=[]
for name, price in zip(soup.select('.q-carline'),soup.select('.q-value')):
    car_name.append(name.text)
    car_price.append(price.text)

df = pd.DataFrame({"car_name":car_name,"car_price":car_price})
print(df)
```

**Output**:

```
                           car_name                       car_price
0                              ADAM  € 14.120,00 nur Lagerfahrzeuge
1                        ADAM ROCKS  € 16.475,00 nur Lagerfahrzeuge
2                      ADAM ROCKS S                     € 20.430,00
3                            ADAM S                    € 19.330,00 
4                          Ampera-e                     € 42.990,00
5                     Astra 5-Türer                     € 19.990,00
6               Astra Sports Tourer                     € 20.990,00
7                           Cascada  € 33.995,00 nur Lagerfahrzeuge
8                        Combo Life                     € 21.645,00
9                       Neuer Corsa                     € 13.990,00
10                          Corsa-e                     € 29.900,00
11                    Corsa 3-Türer                     € 13.255,00
12                    Corsa 5-Türer                     € 14.055,00
13                      Crossland X                     € 18.750,00
14                      Grandland X                     € 24.700,00
15             Insignia Grand Sport                     € 28.505,00
16                     Insignia GSi                     € 46.695,00
17           Insignia Sports Tourer                     € 29.505,00
18          Insignia Country Tourer                     € 41.385,00
19                             KARL                     € 13.350,00
20                       KARL ROCKS                     € 12.965,00
21                          Mokka X                     € 20.495,00
22                           Zafira                     € 28.495,00
23                      Zafira Life                     € 34.780,00
24                      Combo Cargo                     € 20.230,00
25                     Movano Cargo                     € 27.925,00
26              Movano Doppelkabine                     € 38.288,25
27  Movano Fahrgestell Normalkabine                     € 34.777,75
28  Movano Fahrgestell Doppelkabine                     € 35.967,75
29      Movano Plattformfahrgestell                     € 34.777,75
30              Movano Kofferaufbau                     € 46.320,75
31     Movano Pritsche Normalkabine                     € 37.574,25
32     Movano Pritsche Doppelkabine                     € 38.764,25
33              Movano Kofferaufbau                     € 46.320,75
34     Movano Pritsche Normalkabine                     € 37.574,25
35     Movano Pritsche Doppelkabine                     € 38.764,25
36       Movano Kipper Normalkabine                     € 39.894,75
37       Movano Kipper Doppelkabine                     € 44.178,75
38                     Vivaro Cargo                     € 29.750,00
39              Vivaro Doppelkabine                     € 33.082,00
40                     Vivaro Kombi                     € 31.237,50
41              Grandland X Hybrid4                     € 51.165,00
42                     Movano Kombi                     € 30.905,00
```

**Snapshot**:

[image]

Comment: Amazing! This is what i want :) Thanks @KunduK

Comment: @KunduK I tried to find this json url frm network but i didnt able to find that specific url. Can you explain a bit more...

Comment: Once you go to network tab click on XHR tab and do ctlr+R you will see the link which returns data as json when click on response tab.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you are committed to using BeautifulSoup, but you can solve this problem with some plain old Selenium.

Using the URL https://www.opel.de/auswahlhilfe/modelle.html you provided, these samples may get you started.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# start the driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

# navigate to the URL
driver.get("https://www.opel.de/auswahlhilfe/modelle.html")

# invoke WebDriverWait to wait for page to load
# get the model names
model_names = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//a/div/div/div/span[contains(@class, 'q-carline')]")))

for model in model_names:
    print(model.text)
```

To get a list of prices:

```
prices = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a/div/div/div/span[contains(@class, 'q-price')]/span[contains(@class, 'q-value')]");

for price in prices:
    print(price.text)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Are you using any other library because you used 'driver'?

Comment: `name 'driver' is not defined ` Just getting error.

Comment: Driver is the Selenium Webdriver. You have to actually start a driver first. Updated my code sample.

Comment: Thanks. But still getting exception error: `WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`

Comment: You need to do exactly what the error message is telling you to do -- add chromedriver.exe to your Path environment variable. There are plenty of guides and tutorials to show you exactly how to do this. Here's one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path

Answer (score 1):

Use `requests` rather than`urllib.request`...

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.opel.de/auswahlhilfe/modelle.html"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
text = soup.get_text()
print(text)
```

Comment: Thanks @Moshe but how i can generate list? I am fetching the text and  Its clean text but not sure how to create list of models from that...

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanShahid see KunduK's answer... he did the work!

Answer (score 1):

You can get some of the data back from json response. Just would have to phish out what you can get from there:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'https://www.opel.de/apps/atomic/getVehicleTeasers.path=L2NvbnRlbnQvb3BlbC93b3JsZHdpZGUvZ2VybWFueS9kZS9pbmRleC9iYXNlYmFsbC1jYXJkcy9iYmMtY29sbGVjdGlvbnMvdmVoaWNsZXMtb25seS1jb2xsZWN0aW9uPuGlIfE.feefoEnabled=false.expandingMenuEnabled=false.json'

jsonData = requests.get(url).json()['bbcTeaser']

for each in jsonData:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(each)

    carline = soup.find('span', {'class':'q-carline'}).text
    price = soup.find('span', {'class':'q-value'}).text

    print (carline, price)
```

**Output:**

```
ADAM € 14.120,00 nur Lagerfahrzeuge
ADAM ROCKS € 16.475,00 nur Lagerfahrzeuge
ADAM ROCKS S € 20.430,00
ADAM S € 19.330,00 
Ampera-e € 42.990,00
Astra 5-Türer € 19.990,00
Astra Sports Tourer € 20.990,00
Cascada € 33.995,00 nur Lagerfahrzeuge
Combo Life € 21.645,00
Neuer Corsa € 13.990,00
Corsa-e € 29.900,00
Corsa 3-Türer € 13.255,00
Corsa 5-Türer € 14.055,00
Crossland X € 18.750,00
Grandland X € 24.700,00
Insignia Grand Sport € 28.505,00
Insignia GSi € 46.695,00
Insignia Sports Tourer € 29.505,00
Insignia Country Tourer € 41.385,00
KARL € 13.350,00
KARL ROCKS € 12.965,00
Mokka X € 20.495,00
Zafira € 28.495,00
Zafira Life € 34.780,00
Combo Cargo € 20.230,00
Movano Cargo € 27.925,00
Movano Doppelkabine € 38.288,25
Movano Fahrgestell Normalkabine € 34.777,75
Movano Fahrgestell Doppelkabine € 35.967,75
Movano Plattformfahrgestell € 34.777,75
Movano Kofferaufbau € 46.320,75
Movano Pritsche Normalkabine € 37.574,25
Movano Pritsche Doppelkabine € 38.764,25
Movano Kofferaufbau € 46.320,75
Movano Pritsche Normalkabine € 37.574,25
Movano Pritsche Doppelkabine € 38.764,25
Movano Kipper Normalkabine € 39.894,75
Movano Kipper Doppelkabine € 44.178,75
Vivaro Cargo € 29.750,00
Vivaro Doppelkabine € 33.082,00
Vivaro Kombi € 31.237,50
Grandland X Hybrid4 € 51.165,00
Movano Kombi € 30.905,00
```