# UnboundLocalError from Splinter?

Tags: python, linux, firefox, browser, splinter

I installed Firefox and using Ubuntu 18.04.

```py
from splinter import Browser

with Browser() as browser:
    # Visit URL
    url = "http://www.google.com"
    browser.visit(url)
```

Results in:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    with Browser() as browser:
  File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/SupremeBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 90, in Browser
    return get_driver(driver, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/SupremeBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 68, in get_driver
    raise e
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    with Browser() as browser:
  File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/SupremeBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 90, in Browser
    return get_driver(driver, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/SupremeBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 68, in get_driver
    raise e
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    with Browser() as browser:
  File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/SupremeBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 90, in Browser
    return get_driver(driver, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/SupremeBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 68, in get_driver
    raise e
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment
```

I'm not sure how to solve this problem. I checked the documentation from Splinter but there is no hint for this error.

What I am doing wrong ?

After updating the Stringer Lib:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 3, in <module>
    with Browser() as browser:
  File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/SupremeBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 92, in Browser
    return get_driver(driver, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/SupremeBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 70, in get_driver
    raise err
  File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/SupremeBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/browser.py", line 66, in get_driver
    return driver(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/SupremeBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/splinter/driver/webdriver/firefox.py", line 88, in __init__
    **kwargs
  File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/SupremeBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 164, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/sebastian/PycharmProjects/SupremeBot/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
    os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Comment: It looks like a bug in their code.

Comment: It looks like you're using an outdated version though, as the [code on Github](https://github.com/cobrateam/splinter/blob/35c9227f4924bad83e4864ed91a58f9d7d94ca43/splinter/browser.py#L55) doesn't even have that line. This may have been a bug that they patched already.

Comment: @Carcigenicate thank you for your reply ! I updated my Stringer Lib with the code from Github. Now i get new Error which i cant explain..

Comment: I would need to see the error to be able to help.

Comment: @Carcigenicate added to the question below

Answer (score 1):

Finally it works ! I had to update the Splinter lib from Github and put the Geckodriver file into the /usr/bin

Comment: Hi @Lapinski, I'm facing the same problem. I updated splinter using git but I'm running windows, so what's equivelant for /user/bin?

Answer (score 1):

First, check your chrome version, by going to "Help-About Google Chrome".

Second, go to https://chromedriver.chromium.org/ AND download the version that matched your current Google Chrome.

Third, then put the Chromedriver into your bin.

For Mac-users, open Finder, then do shift+command+G, and then type  "/usr/local/bin/"

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I realized that the pip install of splinter had a bug in the get_broswer() function in the splinter/browser.py file.

pip install version of splinter that gave error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'e' referenced before assignment`:

```
def get_driver(driver, retry_count=3, *args, **kwargs):
"""Try to instantiate the driver.

Common selenium errors are caught and a retry attempt occurs.
This can mitigate issues running on Remote WebDriver.

"""

    for _ in range(retry_count):
        try:
            return driver(*args, **kwargs)
    except (IOError, HTTPException, WebDriverException, MaxRetryError) as e:
        pass

    raise e
```

GitHub version:

```
def get_driver(driver, retry_count=3, *args, **kwargs):
"""Try to instantiate the driver.

Common selenium errors are caught and a retry attempt occurs.
This can mitigate issues running on Remote WebDriver.

"""
    err = None
    for _ in range(retry_count):
        try:
            return driver(*args, **kwargs)
        except (IOError, HTTPException, WebDriverException, MaxRetryError) as e:
            err = e

    raise err
```

After updating to the GitHub version, I was able to find the real root cause problem, which was that I was using an older version of setting up chromedriver. I found a good solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52878725/12087852) for that issue.

In this solution, [Navarasu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10474999/navarasu) suggests you `pip install webdriver-manager`, then you can call your browser as follows:

```
from splinter import Browser
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

executable_path = {'executable_path': ChromeDriverManager().install()}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path)
```

A similar approach can be used for Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issues. I reverted back to splinter-0.11.0.

To expand on the last issue for Windows: 
Download the appropriate geckodriver (https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases) and put the geckodriver.exe file into the location your PATH variable is referring to.

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome on Windows 10, I made two edits and I'm not sure which one solved the error.

I downgraded my chrome driver version (to one lower than my current version).
I added this line of code.

```
executable_path = {'executable_path': '/usr/bin/chromedriver'}
browser = Browser('chrome', **executable_path, headless=False)
```