# How can i fix this error? (python 3.8) XxXx

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to **scrape** some images on google. and I found this code, but it doesn't work.
How can I fix this error??

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver

search= input('검색어:')
url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={quote_plus(search)}&source=inms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2haUKEwid64aF87LoAhUafd4KHcEtBZEQ_AUoAXoECBgQAw&biw=1536&bih=754'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
img = soup.select('.rg_i.Q4LuWd.tx8vtf') 
n = 1
imgurl = []
for i in img:
    try:
        imgurl.append(i.attrs['src'])
    except KeyError:
        imgurl.append(i.attrs["data-src"])

for i in imgurl:
    urlretrieve(i,"크롤링 사진/"+ search + ".jpg")
    n +=1
    print(imgurl)

driver.close()
```

(검색어 means 'search term' in korean.)

error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] 지정된 파일을 찾을 수 없습니다

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "yt.py", line 10, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\u\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Thank you for your help.

---

Comment: I assume it is the second issue: "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install webdriver-manager

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from urllib.parse import quote_plus
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
# importing the installed package
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

search= input('검색어:')
url = f'https://www.google.com/search?q={quote_plus(search)}&source=inms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2haUKEwid64aF87LoAhUafd4KHcEtBZEQ_AUoAXoECBgQAw&biw=1536&bih=754'

                          # this will install chromedriver manager 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get(url)

html = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
img = soup.select('.rg_i.Q4LuWd.tx8vtf') 
n = 1
imgurl = []
for i in img:
    try:
        imgurl.append(i.attrs['src'])
    except KeyError:
        imgurl.append(i.attrs["data-src"])

for i in imgurl:
    urlretrieve(i,"크롤링 사진/"+ search + ".jpg")
    n +=1
    print(imgurl)

driver.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing `chromedriver.exe` or if you have installed it it's not on your path. Chromedriver is necessary to run Selenium.

Follow the instructions here to add it...

Download chromedriver: https://chromedriver.chromium.org/

Add it to path: https://developers.refinitiv.com/sites/default/files/How%20To%20Add%20ChromeDriver%20To%20System%20Variables_0.pdf