# Error "chromedriver" executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: '' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home` problem arises when I try to run this code. I have downloaded the file from the link and unzipped the it to my download folder like shown:  C:\Users\Alexandr\Downloads\chromedriver_win32  . Then I put the path to the executable binary (C:\Users\michael\Downloads\chromedriver_win32) into the Environment Variable "Path".

I found the same [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path) on StackOverflow and they say I should type `chromedriver` in cmd and get something like this `tarting ChromeDriver 2.15.322448`, in my case I get `"chromedriver" is not inner or outer command`(this was a translation from my native language).
What should I do in this case

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

class InstaBot:

    def __init__(self, username, password):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get('https://www.instagram.com/?hl=ru')
        sleep(2)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"username\"]") \
            .send_keys(username)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name=\"password\"]") \
            .send_keys(password)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]') \
            .click()
        sleep(4)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[contains(text()."Не сейчас")]').click()


InstaBot('_max_leva_', here is my password)
```

This is error code:

```
C:\Users\Alexandr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe C:/PythonProjects/python/LearningPython/main1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Alexandr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\Alexandr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 854, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\Alexandr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Не удается найти указанный файл

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/PythonProjects/python/LearningPython/main1.py", line 27, in <module>
    InstaBot('_max_leva_', '447781470659')
  File "C:/PythonProjects/python/LearningPython/main1.py", line 14, in __init__
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\Users\Alexandr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\Users\Alexandr\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Environment Variable:

`%PATH%:C:\Users\Alexandr\Downloads\chromedriver_win32`

Comment: you can check if that path is available when you ```import os``` and then ```print(os.environ['PATH'])``` in your code.

Comment: You need to set path , seems like in error there is no chromedriver file

Comment: after setting `PATH` you should check if you can run `chromedriver.exe` in console/terminal in any folder (without full path to `chromedriver.exe`).

Comment: BTW: as I remeber in Windows you have to use `;` in `PATH` to separate paths but you use `:` which is used in `Linux`  - `%PATH%;C:\Users\Alexandr\Downloads\chromedriver_win32`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()`, pass the path to the executable as an argument in the parentheses.

For example:

`self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:/user/Downloads/chromedriver.exe')`