# How to open up Microsoft Edge using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, microsoft-edge, selenium-edgedriver

I've already added the msedge driver into the path variable.

cmd confirmed that MSEdgeDriver was started successfully,

however, when I run

---

```
import os

from selenium import webdriver

browser2 = webdriver.Edge()
```

---

I get an exception error that says

```
"WebDriverException: Message: 'MicrosoftWebDriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH."
```

help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Answer (score 2):

As per the documentation in [Use WebDriver (Chromium) for test automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=python), you need to follow the steps mentioned below:

- [*Install Microsoft Edge (Chromium)*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=python#install-microsoft-edge-chromium): *Ensure you have installed [Microsoft Edge (Chromium)](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge). To confirm that you have Microsoft Edge (Chromium) installed, go to `edge://settings/help` in the browser, and verify the version number is Version 75 or later*.
- [*Download Microsoft Edge Driver*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=python#download-microsoft-edge-driver):

  - *Go to `edge://settings/help` to get the version of Edge.*

[image: edge-version.png]

- *Navigate to the [Microsoft Edge Driver downloads](https://developer.microsoft.com/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/#downloads) page and download the driver that matches the Edge version number.*

[image: edge]

---

### Code Block

Now, you can use the following code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\msedgedriver.exe')
driver.get('edge://settings/help')
print("Page title is: %s" %(driver.title))
#driver.quit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but is there anyway to run webdriver.Edge just as webdriver.Edge() without the executable path?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to open your driver without specifying path of your executable driver every-time you try to launch, Place the msedgedriver.exe's path into PATH (on Windows computer ).
Then you can call default constructor of Web Driver class as below:

```
browser2 = webdriver.Edge()
```

Comment: I added it to the system variables PATH, but it still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Make sure that the name of the PE file matches the expected one. Currently, it is `MicrosoftWebDriver.exe`. Otherwise, set a debug point where Selenium fails when locating the executable and inspect the expected file name.

Answer (score 0):

You should rename the drivername.exe to MicrosoftWebDriver.exe.
This file is taken from the path that you set in the environmental variables

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for this issue: go to the path with the edge driver and rename it.
from **msedgedriver** to **MicrosoftWebDriver**. This should resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to download the browser driver from [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/tools/webdriver/)
2. After the download completes, extract the driver executable to your preferred location. Add the folder where the executable is located to your PATH environment variable.

More details can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium/?tabs=python)