# Open edge browser with selenium. Path error

Tags: python

This is the error I keep getting. I have searched google multiple times trying to figure this issue out. I have added msedgedriver.exe to the PATH several times in a few different locations on my pc. I followed this:
[How to open up Microsoft Edge using Selenium and Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63529124/how-to-open-up-microsoft-edge-using-selenium-and-python)

This is what I am trying to run.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\msedgedriver.exe')
driver.get('edge://settings/help')
print("Page title is: %s" %(driver.title))
#driver.quit()
```

this is the error:

```
 from selenium import webdriver
>>>
>>> driver = webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\msedgedriver.exe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\tut3p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 72, in start
    self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,
  File "C:\Users\tut3p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Users\tut3p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\subprocess.py", line 1435, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\tut3p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\edge\webdriver.py", line 56, in __init__
    self.edge_service.start()
  File "C:\Users\tut3p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'msedgedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please download from http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=619687
```

Please someone help. lol this is driving me nuts. Thank you :)

Removing r from

```
driver =webdriver.Edge(executable_path=r'C:\path\to\msedgedriver.exe')
```

Comment: Try moving `msedgedriver.exe` file to `C:\Program Files (x86)`

Comment: Or try to just remove the `r` that is in your `executeble_path`

Comment: I tried that and I got a access is denied error:
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Comment: removing r worked!! Can you explain, please?

Comment: Usually you use `r` to indicate that you want to read the file, but in this case that will not work for a webdriver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downloading the webdriver manually has always led to problems... unless of course you are very careful in your methods. Here's an alternative... use the webdriver_manager library (https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) to download and handle the driver by itself.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

edge = webdriver.Edge(EdgeChromiumDriverManager().install())
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

I would also recommend you to use the chromedriver rather than the edgedriver since chrome is more robust and well tuned for such applications.

Comment: I'm confused on how to run this. I have installed the manager via pip. I run into this error when I try to run the above:
>>> from selenium import webdriver
>>> from webdriver_manager.microsoft import EdgeChromiumDriverManager
>>> from webdriver_manager import ChromeDriverManager
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'ChromeDriverManager' from 'webdriver_manager' (C:\Users\tut3p\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\__init__.py)
@PreciXon

Comment: Sorry about that, there's a small error in the input statement for ChromeDriverManager. Fixed it now.