# how to run selenium automated scripts in cpanel

Tags: python, flask, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, cpanel

I have developed a python script for selenium automation. Which is automatically open the selenium chrome browser and login into a particular website. It works perfect in the localhost server. Now I deployed it into the cpanel server by following [this](https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/10048/2182/how-to-work-with-python-app) tutorial. But when I start to run it it says `500 Internal Server Error`.

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("start-maximized")
options.add_argument("disable-infobars")
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--headless")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path='chromedriver')
wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
```

error is causing fro the above code.

I checked with the error log

`selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home`

But `chromedriver` and the script are in the same directory
I added `option('--headless')` in the code
please help me to overcome this error.
I'm very beginner in cpanel

Comment: I believe you can find your answer in this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path

Comment: no this not working I'm hosting on it cpanel

Answer (score 0):

By default, `.` eg, current directory is not in PATH on linux/osx shells.

Also, even if would be, there might be a chance that the python script is started with working directory different than where it actually is located.

You need to either at the location where your chromedriver is located to PATH before executing the python script, or provide that path as absolute location or, try to location the chromedriver binary before creating Chrome instance and pass it to executable_path