# chrome driver install with selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have properly install selenium and chromedriver and wanted to execute this below code at python

```
import selenium
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\SM.Nibir\Desktop\Python\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
```

but I am getting these errors on my output panel

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/SM. Nibir/Desktop/Python/import os.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start
    raise WebDriverException(
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
```

Who can I solve this problem and make this code work properly?

Comment: Have you even read the error message?:
`Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Comment: from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"F:/Web Development/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")  this is not working also

Answer (score 0):

first of all, your first mistake is that you wrote "import selenium from.."
so the order has to be that way:

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\...chromedriver.exe")
```

ofcourse that you need to change the path for the correct location of your chromedriver.exe file.

let me know if it helps.

Comment: I also tried this:  from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\SM. Nibir\Desktop\Python\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")    but getting  File "c:/Users/SM. Nibir/Desktop/Python/practices.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Users\SM. Nibir\Desktop\Python\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
  File "C:\python\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 76, in __init__
    RemoteWebDriver.__init__(

Comment: can you edit your question with the current error?,
the full one. i will solve it dont worry