# How to _scrape_ all the data from this website link using selenium and save the extracted city, location and contact number as csv dataframe object?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

The website url to **scrape** data
http://jawedhabib.co.in/hairandbeautysalons-sl/

Code:

```
lst = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".post-17954.page.type-page.status-publish.hentry").text 
for i in lst: 
    driver.implicitly_wait(2) 
    city = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text     
    salon_address = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text 
    Contact_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text    
print(lst)
```

Comment: lst = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".post-17954.page.type-page.status-publish.hentry").text
for i in lst:
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    city = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text
    salon_address = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text
    Contact_number = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text
    
    print(lst)

Comment: Your `lst` is a *string*! You simply iterates through characters in string. What is the point? Did you mean `lst = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".post-17954.page.type-page.status-publish.hentry")`?

Comment: I can't figure out the elements to which i'll iterate and extract all the data mentioned under <td> tags.

Comment: `city = i.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text`

Comment: It is returning some long code snippet after executing lst = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.wpb_wrapper")
for i in lst:
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    city = i.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text
    salon_address = i.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text
    contact_number = i.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text
    print(lst)

Comment: [<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="954897e7d80025af8786c68e322d702f", element="518d2941-76fa-4268-9443-e16f26b0998f")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="954897e7d80025af8786c68e322d702f", element="de03d2dc-82d8-4da5-8de8-2abc456a8d66")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="954897e7d80025af8786c68e322d702f", element="116d652c-510c-41a4-87d8-337b958f387d")>, <selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="954897e7d80025af8786c68e322d702f", element="d419c271-aa29-4dfa-8f12-5148ef474d4f")>, <selenium.webdriver.

Comment: The bot has go to each of the pages with different categories such as hair expresso, hair yoga and should select the text data using selectors and save it in the same format  with respective column names in a pandas DataFrame.The output will be a single dataframe with data of all the pages and you will convert the data to a csv file using the df.to_csv function.

Comment: Instead of `print(lst)`. Put `print(city, salon_address, contact_number)` into `for` loop

Comment: lst = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.post-17954.page.type-page.status-publish.hentry")
for i in lst:
    driver.implicitly_wait(2)
    table_row = i.find_element_by_css_selector(".vc_row.wpb_row.vc_row-fluid").text
    for j in table_row:
        city = j.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text
        salon_address = j.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text
        contact_number = j.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text
        print(city, salon_address, contact_number)

Comment: AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-098360f1e84d> in <module>
      4     table_row = i.find_element_by_css_selector(".vc_row.wpb_row.vc_row-fluid").text
      5     for j in table_row:
----> 6         city = j.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text
      7         salon_address = j.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text
      8         contact_number = j.find_element_by_css_selector("tr").text

AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_css_selector'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the first part of your problem. Starting from the start you need to wait for all elements to load onto the screen. Grab all tables trs that are beyond the first 2 trs which are reserved for the location. From the tr xpath to their child using ./ and grab the td[1-3] text using the attribute('textContent') respectfully.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 60)
driver.get("http://jawedhabib.co.in/hairandbeautysalons-sl/")
#driver.maximize_window()
tableValues=wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH,"//tbody//tr[position()>2]")))
city=[]
address=[]
contactno=[]
for tr in tableValues:
    #print(tr.get_attribute('textContent'))
    city.append(tr.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").get_attribute('textContent'))
    address.append(tr.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").get_attribute('textContent'))
    contactno.append(tr.find_element_by_xpath("./td[3]").get_attribute('textContent'))
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Comment: Grab all tables trs that are beyond the first 2 trs which are reserved for the location. What does reserved table mean

Comment: CENTRAL ZONE  
City Salon Address Contact No basically ignoring those rows

Comment: I want to add a user agent and I am doing it as: from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options   opts = Options()
opts.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.190 Safari/537.36")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=opts)   but there is error

Comment: I am getting file not found error and a webdriverexception is raised Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path you need to set up your chromedriver.

Comment: also chrome_options is depreciated use options