# Getting chrome driver not in path when moving my selenium executable to another computer

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, pyinstaller

I wrote a small automation script using Python and Selenium Web Driver and I made it into an executable and the executable worked fine on my computer but when I tried it on another computer I got that `chromedriver` isn't in path (**note**: I included `chromedriver` using the `add binary` command and both computers are running the same operating system: `Mac OS`)

I am not quite sure why this happened, my suspicion is the following:

In my `.py` code I used the following two lines to initiate the `chromedriver`

```
path = "/Users/sergio/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
```

However, the other computer doesn't even have this path so might be causing it even has this path. Now one might suggest simply using `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` but here comes the bigger problem: I tried having my `chromedriver` in a system path like `/usr/local/bin` and when I did that `driver = webdriver.Chrome()` worked but compiling the program using pyinstaller didn't work, I ran:
`pyinstaller --onefile --noconsole --add-binary 'usr/local/bin/chromedriver:.' finalregtool.py`
but I got a lot of errors including `Unable to find "/Users/sergio/usr/local/bin/chromedriver" when adding binary and data files`

This led to me thinking that `pyinstaller` automatically adds `/Users/sergio` to the given path which makes my path wrong so I had to use something inside `/Users/sergio` , I tried putting my `chromedriver` in `Applications` but compilation resulted in not finding the path again, for some reasons compilation worked when the path was `/Users/sergio/chromedriver` so I went with this path but the code didn't work anymore (`chromedriver` not found in path) so I had to specify the path manually.

Now I am kind of stuck in a deadlock not knowing what to do. Any help would be appreciated. I hope my explanation was clear enough.

My only end goal is compiling my selenium script and running it on other computers without having them install anything extra, I don't care how this should be done so if anyone has a solution outside pyinstaller I don't mind.

Update: added a bounty

Answer (score 1):

There're couple of good solutions for that issue:

1.Install [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) package:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

what I prefer mostly and use it like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

2.Launch Remote Selenium Hub called [Selenoid](https://github.com/aerokube/selenoid) and lauch browser remotely:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='ip_of_your_selenoid_instance:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

3.You can launch [Chrome docker container](https://hub.docker.com/r/selenium/standalone-chrome/) and also going to by remote url, what will be always localhost:

```
driver = webdriver.Remote(command_executor='http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub',desired_capabilities=DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch a standalone chrome browser:

```
docker run -d -p 4444:4444 selenium/standalone-chrome
```

and then in your python script launch browser using Remote webdriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities
driver = webdriver.Remote("http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub", DesiredCapabilities.CHROME)
```

docker-compose:

```
# docker-compose.yml

selenium:
  image: selenium/standalone-firefox
  ports:
  - 4444:4444
```

Answer (score 0):

`pyinstaller` unpacks everything into a temporary directory during execution of exe, when using the `--onefile` mode. Refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44352931/14094985) answer and the related post to get an idea about how to get the correct relative path. You might have to use

```py
path = resource_path("chromedriver")
```

Also, you can directly add the `chromedriver` to `PATH` environment variable in the runtime so you wouldn't have to specify the path explicitly and you can simply call `webdriver.Chrome()`

```py
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + resource_path("chromedriver")
```

`pyinstaller` conciders `usr/local/bin/chromedriver:.` as a relative path, thus adds `/Users/sergio` in an attempt to make it absolute, try using a different location. This location doesn't matter anyway, once this file is found `pyinstaller` will add this to the root directory of the compiled exe, and unpack it when the exe is executed.

Answer (score 0):

The modern way to deal with the chromedriver binary is to use [WebDriverManager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/).
First you need to install the manager:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

Then you use it (for Chrome):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

In my .NET Core project I use not the most modern approach I have described, but the latest stable NuGet from here https://www.nuget.org/packages/Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver/.
Basically the nuget contains the chromedriver and copies it every time to your assembly folder (\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1 in my case). This is the line I have in my project:

```
"<PackageReference Include="Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver" Version="*" />"
```

The star means the latest (highest number) stable package will be used as explained [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/package-versioning#floating-version-resolutions). Of course you can install the latest version manually, and then on each 2 major Chrome versions to update the NuGet package reference so that is matches your Chrome version. (87 chromedriver works with 87 and 88 Chrome, but not with 89).
Then the driver is instantiated with this lines:

```
var driver = new ChromeDriver(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
```

References:
[Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)
https://www.automatetheplanet.com/webdriver-net50/

Comment: thank you for this, what about packaging into using pyinstaller? that was the main issue

Comment: My suggestion is to try one of the two suggested approaches by me on the original computer. In both cases you do not need to specify a path to chromedriver.exe. That is why I hope that pyinstaller will not have issue with that path.

Answer (score 0):

```
path = "/Users/sergio/chromedriver"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
```

Change the above code to the following format

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Users/sergio/chromedriver.exe')
```