# How to add chromedriver.exe to PATH?

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, webdriver

I have the webdriver and selenium installed. When I try to run a code to just open google, I get this error. I have tried adding the .exe to the path many times, but it isn't working.

Message=Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: What exactly the problem you facing with?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Comment: please provide the code you're trying.

Answer (score 4):

Now you can set chromedriver for auto upgradation :

`pip install chromedriver-autoinstaller`

code :

```
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_autoinstaller


chromedriver_autoinstaller.install()  # Check if the current version of chromedriver exists
                                      # and if it doesn't exist, download it automatically,
                                      # then add chromedriver to path

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
```

try the below code for manual setup :

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome("full path to chrome driver\\chromedriver.exe")
driver.maximize_window()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
driver.get("www.google.com")
```

Answer (score 3):

Install the driver at the time of execution.
Using the `webdriver_manager` python package will store this into a cache and pass the exact path to the driver.
**It will only download if a newer driver version exists.**

```
import selenium
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```