# WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver_win32.exe' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, python-3.x

[When I read the chromedriver file path, it occurs this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vmSO.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips. [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/4518341). Instead, copy the text, [edit] it into your post, and use the formatting tools like [code formatting](/editing-help#code).

Answer (score 1):

The `r` of a raw-string must come before the quotes, not in the quotes.

```
chromedriver = r"C:\Users\...."
```

---

Btw: Your URL `http:google.com` (the scheme) is no valid too.

```
driver.get("http://google.com")
```

would be correct.
or better:

```
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

Comment: After deleting the "r", the error still the same

Comment: You should not delete the `r`, you should move it.

Comment: (WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver_win32.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home)

THIS IS THE ERROR AFTER I ADDING 'r' BEFORE THE QUOTE, NEED HELP!

Comment: In the screenshot of your question the path doesn't end with `.exe.`. afaik this must point to the file (with the extension), so add it. Check also [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path) out.

Comment: I have updated my screenshot, but it is same error again.

Comment: Please note that questions caused by a typo are off-topic on [so] as per the [help/on-topic]. If you find such questions, flag or vote them as off-topic, depending on your reputation. Leaving a comment on the question is sufficient if you still want to help the OP in such cases.