# WebDriverException: WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new with Selenium and I have this error:

```
WebDriverException: WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH
```

What this error means and how to fix it?

Comment: Usually that error means that you are not specifying the path of the `chromedriver`. Can you please attach the code which gives you that error?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Comment: Please do minimal google search before asking widely asked questions

Answer (score 2):

This happens when the path for the `chromedriver.exe` file is wrong.
The `chromedriver.exe` file can be stored in your local.
Suppose the `.exe` file is in the `C:` drive → `Chromedriver` folder, this would be the correct path:
`"C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe"`

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="C:\Chromedriver\chromedriver.exe")
```