# 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH - Python - Selenium (MAC)

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I keep getting this error:

selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

My Script: (MAC)

```py
from selenium import webdriver

PATH='~ ABC$ /Users/ABC/Desktop/Chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("https://google.com")
```

What should I do? The Path is okay. I though there is something wrong with the format so I added ".exe" to file, but I am getting the same issue.

Note: The browser and package version are the same (96)

Comment: I don't think `~ ABC$ ` should be part of the path. I think the path should just be the part `/Users/ABC/Desktop/Chromedriver/chromedriver.exe`. Does that work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Comment: It worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PATH should contain the Folder Path to your driver.

Having `'~ ABC'` in your path makes it look for something in the `~ ABC` file which does not exsist as a parent file to `/Users/`

Comment: It worked! Thanks.