# Trying to work with selenium and scrapy both

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, scrapy

I am to scrape dynamic website but the selenium will provide me these error `'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH` Can you solve these problem

```
from scrapy import Spider
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from selenium import webdriver


class AuthorSpider(Spider):
    name = 'pushpa'


    def start_requests(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver')
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=options)
        driver.get('https://www.lazada.com.ph/shop-laptops/')
        link_elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
            '//*[@data-qa-locator="product-item"]//a[text()]')

        for link in link_elements:
            yield{
                'url':link
            }
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path

Answer (score 0):

`executable_path` should be set to absolute path to `chromedriver.exe` file containing the `chromedriver.exe` file itself.
So, in case your `chromedriver.exe` is inside the `'C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver'` folder it should be

```py
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
```

Also I don't understand why are you defining and initializing 2 objects of the driver? :

```py
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, options=options)
```

Comment: they will show me these error again

Comment: for what exactly code line?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python39\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 129, in _next_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "C:\Users\Dell\catalogue\catalogue\spiders\pushpa.py", line 12, in start_requests
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')
  File "e:\python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "e:\python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 81, in start

Comment: The error is still `executable needs to be in PATH`? Does the path to the file is `C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe`?

Comment: yes the error will same `executable needs to be in PATH`  yes  the path is in the  C folder  in the computer in program files

Comment: It is strange. Your IDE can not find the `chromedriver.exe` executable file in `'C:/Program Files (x86)/chromedriver/chromedriver.exe'` path. Maybe it is in `Program Files (x86)` folder itself or the folder it is in is not `/chromedriver/`?