# Creating new python Class with Selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium

Good morning.

I'm new to Selenium and I have some issues with Selenium 4.
Basically I'm trying to create a class that will have some custom methods like sending a request to specified URL.
But...I'm stuck at **init** method.
With the code I wrote the browser is starting but it breaks with error message:

> ====== WebDriver manager ====== Current google-chrome version is 101.0.4951 Get LATEST chromedriver version for 101.0.4951 google-chrome Driver
> [/home/agent2/.wdm/drivers/chromedriver/linux64/101.0.4951.41/chromedriver]
> found in cache Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/agent2/1-Python/Selenium-Scrapy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 71, in start
> self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env,   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 966, in **init**
> self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1842, in _execute_child
> raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename) FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'chromedriver'
>
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/agent2/1-Python/Selenium-Scrapy/bot/booking/booking.py", line
> 29, in 
> a = MyBot()   File "/home/agent2/1-Python/Selenium-Scrapy/bot/booking/booking.py", line
> 17, in **init**
> super(MyBot, self).**init**()   File "/home/agent2/1-Python/Selenium-Scrapy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py",
> line 70, in **init**
> super(WebDriver, self).**init**(DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['browserName'], "goog",
> File
> "/home/agent2/1-Python/Selenium-Scrapy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chromium/webdriver.py",
> line 90, in **init**
> self.service.start()   File "/home/agent2/1-Python/Selenium-Scrapy/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py",
> line 81, in start
> raise WebDriverException( selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver'
> executable needs to be in PATH. Please see
> https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

**This is my code:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


class MyBot(webdriver.Chrome):
    """My class"""

    def __init__(
        self,
        driver=webdriver.Chrome(
            service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),
            options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
            )
        ):
        self.driver = driver
        super(MyBot, self).__init__()
        
        
        
    
    def land_first_page(self):
        """My custom method"""

        self.get('My-url')



a = MyBot()
a.land_first_page()
```

To be honest I don't know how to solve this... Found some solutions but with Selenium 3 where you could simply pass a path to driver location.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Comment: It works this way when not in class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because your class inherits from `webdriver.Chrome`, `WebDriver` `__init__` tries to start a service using the chromedriver.exe file, but since you didn't provide a path it uses the default value `executable_path="chromedriver"` which doesn't exists in your project.

Just remove the inheritance and use the `driver` instance `ChromeDriverManager().install()` creates for you.

Comment: Thank You Sir, I was blindly focused on inheritance to access WebDriver's methods. Droping it and replacing self.get with simple self.driver.get works!