# Chrome driver is not in a executable path how to fix this error in Selenium"

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm confused as to what is causing this error:

**The chrome version is 100.0.4986 which is the latest**

[image]

**Python version is 3.9.1:**

[image]

**Chrome web driver version is 100.0:**

[image]

**Path and location of web driver:**

[image]

**Code below based :**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\sanas\OneDrive\CSIT 110 Python\chromedriver.exe')

driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

**Error:**

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnceF.png]

Comment: the OneDrive folder sometimes is tricky. Try to put the chromedriver.exe in Documents or C:

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error message: "'chromedriver' executable needs to be available in the path"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path)

Answer (score 0):

Put your chromedriver.exe in C:\ folder and try this code. The commented line is not necessary for opening new browser it will be used for finding elements on the page.

```
from selenium import webdriver
# from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By 
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
ser = Service('C:\\chromedriver.exe')
opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()

web = webdriver.Chrome(service=ser, options=opt)
web.get('url link you want to open')
```