# Importing a function that uses selenium with ipynb not working on Windows

Tags: python, selenium, jupyter-notebook, selenium-chromedriver, ipython

I wrote a function for scraping data from a website in a Jupyter Notebook. The function works perfectly fine when running in that notebook and when I use `ipynb` to import the functions from that notebook it imports them successfully. Then when I run the function in the second notebook I get: `WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.`. The weirdest part is that this works fine on my MacBook but not on my PC. Has anyone encountered this and found a solution?

The import I use is: `from ipynb.fs.full.my_notebook import my_function`. I then create a dataframe using `df = my_function(x, y, z)`, which is where I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to set the path to `chromedriver` executable instead of using the one in the `PATH`.

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service(executable_path='/Users/<user_name>/Downloads/chromedriver')

...
```

Comment: I still get the same error using this method.

Comment: I've found an answer in the following link. Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858752/error-message-chromedriver-executable-needs-to-be-available-in-the-path