# Selenium ChromeDriverManager doesn't downloads the latest version of ChromeDriver

Tags: python-3.x, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-manager, webdrivermanager-python

I have an error:

```
E       selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 102
E       Current browser version is 109.0.5414.120 with binary path C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
```

I have already used the code to get latest version of webdriver-

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.set_capability("acceptInsecureCerts", True)

        preferences = {"profile.default_content_settings.popups": 0,
                       "download.default_directory": r""+Constants.path+"",
                       # IMPORTANT - ENDING SLASH V IMPORTANT
                       "directory_upgrade": True}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", preferences)

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=options)
```

With this same code I am able to run this code on my local machine(i.e. laptop) but this code is not working on my Virtual machine.
the chrome version on both machine is same i.e. - 109.0.5414.120.

Please guide.

Comment: one week ago this code was working fine. This error starts coming from Friday(27Jan2023).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On my virtual machine, I found that there are two different versions(one latest and one older version) of chrome installed at two different locations. Therefore I uninstalled both chrome and deleted all chrome/google associated folders and files then install a fresh version of the google chrome browser. Finally, the code runs successfully.

Comment: Mark this answer as a solution please.

Answer (score 3):

your problem is as below: this `ChromeDriverManager().install()` will get LATEST chromedriver version -in my case today, it is 115.0.5790- at

> https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/

but on their site
[image: LATEST chromedriver version has not been ready to be installed]

update: it seems more exact, you can view [ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114 Current browser version is 116.0.5845.111 - (Selenium version - 3.141.59)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76970623/chromedriver-only-supports-chrome-version-114-current-browser-version-is-116-0-5)

this is not error of code, it is one of library or because of chrome's changing

-> LATEST chromedriver version has not been ready to be installed

solution is, as @kaliiiiiiiii said, `driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager(version="114.0.5735.16").install(), options=options)`

Answer (score 3):

While the answers here are correct, however, for future readers, there are notable changes.

1. `ChromeDriverManager()` is no longer required in `Selenium` version v4.6.0 and greater.
   See [Selenium documentation](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location/): *As of Selenium 4.6, Selenium downloads the correct driver for you. You shouldn’t need to do anything.*.
2. In [`Selenium manager 4.10.0`](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e) (released 07 Jun '23), the `executable_path` was removed.
   However, one can still pass in an executable_path, using the `service arg`:
   `service=Service(executable_path='path_to_chromedriver')`
   This is not recommended.

Readers should refer to answers from this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76553813/messageunable-to-obtain-chromedriver-using-selenium-manager).

PS: `Selenium manager 4.11.0` is now released: 31 Jul '23.

Answer (score 2):

Try using:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager(version="109.0.5414.74").install(), options=options)
```

[resource](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager#version)

Comment: this code does not work, It gives the below error-


`raise ValueError(f"There is no such driver by url {resp.url}")
ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/109.0.5414.120/chromedriver_win32.zip

Process finished with exit code 1`

Comment: Just updated my answer, does it now work?

Comment: you have a shortage of double quote =)) thanks for your solution, it is helpful

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers suggested by others, simply upgrading your selenium `webdriver-manager` to the latest version may also help - at least in some cases.

```
pip install webdriver-manager --upgrade
```

Answer (score 0):

That worked for me using latest version 117
It unblocked me from this error message :
"ValueError: There is no such driver by url [https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_117.0.5938"](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_117.0.5938%22)

All the pushed changes:
installed seleniumbase as replacement for legacy selenium :
 -->  pip install seleniumbase
upgraded wrapper :
 --> pip install --upgrade pyhtml2pdf
upgraded webdriver-manager :
--> pip install webdriver-manager --upgrade
updated the code
from :
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(...)
To:
from seleniumbase import Driver
driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=False)

#more info about new selenium 4.11 options available -> https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/master/seleniumbase/plugins/driver_manager.py