# Message:Unable to obtain chromedriver using Selenium Manager

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, webdriver

I've tried writing this code on my jupyter notebook, and it shows me the error. My objective is to carry out web scrapping.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYwU8.png)

I've also installed selenium using pip and webdriver-manager using pip as well.

Comment: could you please show more code?

Answer (score 5):

The output of `ChromeDriverManager().install()` is an `executable_path` to the driver, but `executable_path` was removed in `selenium` `4.10.0`. That's why you're seeing the error after passing the value into `webdriver.Chrome()`. Here are the changes:
https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/commit/9f5801c82fb3be3d5850707c46c3f8176e3ccd8e

[image: Changes_in_selenium_4_10_0]

Note that `executable_path` was removed. If you want to pass in an `executable_path`, you'll have to use the `service` arg now. (`service=Service(executable_path='./chromedriver')`) But Selenium Manager is now fully included with `selenium` `4.10.0`, so this is all you need:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service

service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=options)
# ...
driver.quit()
```

If the driver isn't found on your system PATH, Selenium Manager will automatically download it for you.

Answer (score 2):

### [Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)

Selenium Manager is the new tool that helps to get the required browser drivers to run [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) out of the box. ***Beta 1*** of Selenium Manager configures the browser drivers for Chrome, Firefox, and Edge if they are not present on the `PATH`. So To run a Selenium test with Selenium 4.6 and onwards you just need to have [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) or [microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) installed. If you already have browser drivers installed, this feature will be ignored completely.

---

### Current Status

[Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/selenium_manager/) tool is still in beta phase and Selenium is gradually adding support for this feature. The current implementation is a *`fall-back`* option, which means it should only get used if the code execution would otherwise fail. So long as you specify the location of the driver in the appropriate `Service` class (or using [System Properties](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60061951/7429447) in Java), the Selenium Manager will not be used.

---

### Solution

There are 2 different approaches as follows:

- You can totally avoid [webdriver-manager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447) and your effective code block will be:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome()
  ```
- To keep using the [webdriver-manager](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) you have to use the [Service](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70537951/7429447) class and your effective code block will be:

  ```
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeDriverManager().install())
  ```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try by removing the `ChromeDriverManager`, you don't need it if your selenium version is `v4.6.0` or above.

Change below:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

To:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

[Introducing Selenium Manager](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/)