# Unable to find the latest chrome driver 114.0.5735.134

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was working on my selenium project my chrome version is 114.0.5735.134 but i don't find the latest chrome driver here https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

how can I run my script?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google recently has changed the build process for Chrome and ChromeDriver. Going forward, all the releases will be available at https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/.
This is done to streamline the Chrome and ChromeDriver versions. Now each Chrome release would have its corresponding same version available.

More details can be found at the following links-
https://developer.chrome.com/blog/chrome-for-testing/

Answer (score 0):

Not sure which selenium version are you using. If you are using Selenium `v4.6.0` or above, you don't have to worry about downloading the `chromedrover.exe`. Selenium's new tool known as `SeleniumManager` will do the job of auto downloading and managing it for you.

[image]

**Reference:**

- https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location/
- https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/

**Python code can be as simple as below:**

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

If you still want to manually download and use the `chromedriver`, then you can use the latest version `114.0.5735.90`. See below for explanation:

[image]

**Reference:** https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads/version-selection

Answer (score 0):

Incase you are using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** and above you don't need to explicitly download [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447), [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) or any browser drivers as such. You just need to ensure that the desired browser client i.e. [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [firefox](/questions/tagged/firefox) or [microsoft-edge](/questions/tagged/microsoft-edge) is installed. [**Selenium Manager**](https://www.selenium.dev/blog/2022/introducing-selenium-manager/) is the new tool that would help to get a working environment to run Selenium out of the box. Beta 1 of [***Selenium Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76555236/7429447) will configure the browser drivers for Chrome, Firefox, and Edge if they are not present on the *`PATH`*.

---

### Solution

As a solution you can simply do:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Answer (score -1):

you can download any driver supports chrome version 114

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).