# TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service' error using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless')  # Run Chrome in headless mode
webdriver_service = Service(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
url = 'https://www.amazon.com'
driver.get(url)
driver.quit()
```

When running this I am getting this error

```
[WDM] - ====== WebDriver manager ======
[WDM] - Current google-chrome version is 114.0.5735
[WDM] - Get LATEST driver version for 114.0.5735
[WDM] - Driver [C:\Users\kanch\.wdm\drivers\chromedriver\win32\114.0.5735.90\chromedriver.exe] found in cache
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\kanch\OneDrive\Desktop\WEB.py", line 14, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=webdriver_service, options=chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

I have invested so much time in it and I am using an old version of selenium and web driver

Comment: The argument service was removed in the newer versions of Selenium, and it seems you're using an older version that still expects it. Update both Selenium and ChromeDriver to their latest versions. You can use the following commands to update them:
pip install --upgrade selenium
webdriver_manager update --force-cache

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'
```

...implies that an unexpected keyword argument ***service*** was passed to the `WebDriver.__init__()`

Possibly you are still using [selenium3](/questions/tagged/selenium3) which doesn't supports the keyword argument `service`

---

### Solution

To use the keyword argument `service` you have to use [selenium4](/questions/tagged/selenium4) and you need to upgrade [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) version as follows:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

or

```
pip3 install -U selenium
```

---

Now using ***Selenium 4***, the `service` keyword and [**webdriver_manager**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447) you can use the following code block:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com')
```

---

Again, using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** and above you won't require the [webdriver-manager](/questions/tagged/webdriver-manager) even.

[***Selenium Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) takes care of downloading the compatible [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) version internally. So your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless=new")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = options)
driver.get('https://www.amazon.com')
```