# How to solve firefox driver's binary problem in selenium?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

Now I want to use selenium for some automation of my website. I have pip-installed selenium and downloaded and unzipped the Firefox binary file. The problem now is that whenever I try to initialize the webdriver, for some reason it cannot use the Firefox driver's binary. Below is my code.
Unfortunately, I do not have write access, so I cannot move the driver's binary to /usr/local/bin or any other similar directory. So I need to store the driver's binary in a custom directory.

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = r'geckodriver'
s = Service(executable_path = r'geckodriver')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(service = s, options = options)
```

This raises the error:

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable
```

So please tell me what did I mess and how to solve this problem. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this way (assuming you're using selenium 4)

```py
from selenium.webdriver import Firefox, FirefoxOptions
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.service import Service as FirefoxService
from webdriver_manager.firefox import GeckoDriverManager

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.binary = r'C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe' # on Windows

driver = Firefox(service=FirefoxService(GeckoDriverManager().install()), options=options)
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

you need to install the `webdriver-manager`:

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

On a Linux server, the installation location of Firefox can vary depending on how it was installed. If Firefox is installed system-wide,

Here are some common paths where you can find the Firefox executable on Linux:

- /usr/bin/firefox
- /usr/lib/firefox/firefox
- /opt/firefox/firefox

reference: https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/#use-with-firefox

Comment: @OmarOshiba, happy to know that, cheers!

Comment: I tried this but I got another error, a pop up appeared with this message: "Your Firefox profile cannot be loaded. It may be missing or inaccessible."

Answer (score 1):

Using [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.6*** and above you don't need the firefox driver's binary explicitly.

---

### Solution

[***Selenium Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) takes care of downloading the compatible [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45331403/7429447) version. So your effective code block will be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.binary_location = '\path\to\firefox'
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options = options)
```

Comment: Well something really strange happened when I tried this code (with passing the binary_location to the webdriver options), it got me the same error:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import FirefoxOptions

options = FirefoxOptions()
options.add_argument('--headless')
firefox_driver = '/Applications/Firefox'
options.binary_location = firefox_driver
driver = webdriver.Firefox(options = options)
driver.get('https://google.com')
print(driver.title)
```

But when I hashed the options.binary_location line it worked. 

What exactly happened?

Comment: @OmarOshiba `'/Applications/Firefox'` is not really the location of _firefox_driver_. firefox_driver i.e [GeckoDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45510453/7429447) is managed by Selenium Manager now.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I will tell you what I've done, and tell me what I missed.
I downloaded the geckodriver and unzipped it. It got me the geckodriver binary. Now when I modify the binary location to be  '/Users/omarmarouf/Desktop/SeleniumEXP/geckodriver'
Which is the location of it on my machine. It says: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: binary is not a Firefox executable

Although this is the actual location of the geckodriver which is working as well.
So what is the problem and how to solve it?