# Chromedriver version 115 not found

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

With chromedriver version above 115, this has stopped working:

> driver = webdriver.Chrome()

with the error

> There is no such driver by url
> https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/LATEST_RELEASE_115.0.5790.

As suggested here [selenium webdriver chrome 115 stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76727774/selenium-webdriver-chrome-115-stopped-working), this works:

> service =
> Service(ChromeDriverManager(version="114.0.5735.90").install())

But that doesn't seem like a good ongoing solution. Is there a better way?

Comment: Check these answers - https://stackoverflow.com/a/76752843/7598774 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/76728148/7598774

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`WebDriver-Manager`](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/) to automaticly update the driver's version.
**Install `webdriver-manager`:**

```py
pip install webdriver-manager
```

**For Chrome:**

```py
# selenium 3
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

```py
# selenium 4
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

Comment: This won't work with 4.10 (arguments changed).

Comment: This worked on my notebook, but on my imac, it doesn't. I still get the error ValueError: There is no such driver by url https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/115.0.5790/chromedriver_mac64.zip

Comment: That's correct - the last released version for mac is: 114.0.5735.90/chromedriver_mac64.zip you can find all versions here: https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/

Comment: In addition try to clean the project - right click on the project and select - clean Python compiled files

Answer (score 2):

The only thing that worked is updating the webdriver-manager to 4.0.0

With this package update the old syntax

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install(), options=chrome_options)
```

started to work again :)

The Service argument is available only from Selenium 4.10

Answer (score 0):

You may try this way:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

and you'll need to install

```
pip install selenium
pip install webdriver-manager
```

references:

- [How to solve firefox driver's binary problem in selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76648381/how-to-solve-firefox-drivers-binary-problem-in-selenium/76660650#76660650)
- [Purpose of webdriver manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76453996/purpose-of-webdriver-manager/76454059#76454059)
- https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install -U selenium webdriver-manager
```

The driver options changed, even though the major version remained, (thus the api is incompatible, bad selenium)

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
# do options stuff
driver_path = ChromeDriverManager().install()
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)  # not chrome_options, no path argument
driver.service.path = driver_path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [webdriver-auto-update](https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-auto-update/) package to automatically download/update the driver's version.

Install `webdriver-auto-update`:

```py
pip install webdriver-auto-update
```

For Chrome:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_auto_update import check_driver

check_driver("C:\\Users\\User\\PycharmProjects") # dir path to store chromedriver in

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('your_website.com')
```

Please note: the dir must already exist, it doesn't create it for you.

I personally prefer to use `os.getcwd() + "\\drivers"` path `os.getcwd()` to get the current dir, and the drivers folder, which I've added to the `.gitignore` file.

Answer (score 0):

I have updated chromedriver to version 115.0.5790.110 on my mac, and it solved the binary not found issue.

https://edgedl.me.gvt1.com/edgedl/chrome/chrome-for-testing/115.0.5790.110/mac-arm64/chromedriver-mac-arm64.zip

Answer (score 0):

I originally came here a few months ago with the same error, and one of the solutions provided in this thread worked. However, it stopped working and it took me some time to find an answer. [Check this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913935/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-message-session-not-crea) for another way to solve any error regarding chromedriver version. I tried it and it solved the issue right away!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for keeping the chromedriver up to date without using webdriver-manager, based on this code: https://gist.github.com/primaryobjects/d5346bf7a173dbded1a70375ff7461b4

It download the driver version that match your chrome version, and put it in the right folder (windows 10)

```
import os
import re
from sys import platform
import urllib.request, json
import zipfile
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import shutil


def extract_version_registry(output):
    try:
        google_version = ''
        for letter in output[output.rindex('DisplayVersion    REG_SZ') + 24:]:
            if letter != '\n':
                google_version += letter
            else:
                break
        return (google_version.strip())
    except TypeError:
        return


def extract_version_folder():
    # Check if the Chrome folder exists in the x32 or x64 Program Files folders.
    for i in range(2):
        path = 'C:\\Program Files' + (' (x86)' if i else '') + '\\Google\\Chrome\\Application'
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            paths = [f.path for f in os.scandir(path) if f.is_dir()]
            for path in paths:
                filename = os.path.basename(path)
                pattern = '\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+'
                match = re.search(pattern, filename)
                if match and match.group():
                    # Found a Chrome version.
                    return match.group(0)

    return None


def get_chrome_version():
    version = None
    install_path = None

    try:
        if platform == "linux" or platform == "linux2":
            # linux
            install_path = "/usr/bin/google-chrome"
        elif platform == "darwin":
            # OS X
            install_path = "/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome"
        elif platform == "win32":
            # Windows...
            try:
                # Try registry key.
                stream = os.popen(
                    'reg query "HKLM\\SOFTWARE\\Wow6432Node\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\Google Chrome"')
                output = stream.read()
                version = extract_version_registry(output)
            except Exception as ex:
                # Try folder path.
                version = extract_version_folder()
    except Exception as ex:
        # print(ex)
        pass

    version = os.popen(f"{install_path} --version").read().strip('Google Chrome ').strip() if install_path else version

    return version


def closest_chrome_version(version, versions):
    closest = [10000000, ""]
    objective = version.split(".")
    for to_test in versions:
        current = to_test["version"].split(".")
        if current[0] == objective[0]:
            gap = 100 * (abs(int(current[1]) - int(objective[1]))) + 10 * (abs(int(current[2]) - int(objective[2]))) + (
                abs(int(current[3]) - int(objective[3])))
            if closest[0] > gap:
                closest = [gap, to_test]
    return closest[1]


def maj_chromedriver():
    print("Chromedriver update in progress")

    # todo: add your path here (can be your download folder for instance)
    path_to_zip = "YOUR PATH/chromedriver.zip"
    path_to_unzip = "YOUR PATH/chromedriver"
    chrome_version = get_chrome_version()
    with urllib.request.urlopen(
            "https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json") as url:
        data = json.load(url)
        for download in closest_chrome_version(chrome_version, data["versions"])["downloads"]["chromedriver"]:
            if download["platform"] == "win64":
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(download["url"], path_to_zip)
                with zipfile.ZipFile(path_to_zip, 'r') as zip_ref:
                    zip_ref.extractall(path_to_unzip)
                    for file in listdir(path_to_unzip + "/" + listdir(path_to_unzip)[0]):
                        if isfile(join(path_to_unzip + "/" + listdir(path_to_unzip)[0], file)) and ".exe" in file:
                            os.system('"taskkill /im chromedriver.exe /f"')
                            try:
                                os.remove("C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe")
                            except Exception as e:
                                print(e)
                            shutil.copyfile(join(path_to_unzip + "/" + listdir(path_to_unzip)[0], file),
                                            "C:/Program Files/Google/Chrome/Application/chromedriver.exe")
                            break
                break
    shutil.rmtree(path_to_unzip)
    os.remove(path_to_zip)
    print("complete")
```