# selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain chromedriver using Selenium Manager error using Selenium and ChromeDriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, seleniummanager

I can't figure out why my code it's always getting an error

This is my code:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://google.com/"
path = "C:/Users/thefo/OneDrive/Desktop/summer 2023/chromedriver_win32"

driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
driver.get(url)
```

Path of chromedriver:

[image: path from chromedriver]

and this is the error that always appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thefo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 42, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\thefo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 74, in driver_location
    browser = options.capabilities["browserName"]
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\thefo\OneDrive\Desktop\summer 2023\Projeto Bot Discord - BUFF SELL CHECKER\teste2.py", line 6, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(path)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\thefo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 47, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, self.options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\thefo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 44, in get_path
    raise NoSuchDriverException(f"Unable to obtain {service.path} using Selenium Manager; {err}")
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain chromedriver using Selenium Manager; 'str' object has no attribute 'capabilities'; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location
```

Comment: use this link `https://stackoverflow.com/a/77815918/12780274`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error message...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\thefo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 42, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

...implies that the version of [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) which you are using is ***v4.6*** or above.

---

### Selenium Manager

In such cases [***Selenium Manager***](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76563271/7429447) can silently download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) and you don't have to explicitly mention the *chromedriver* path anymore.

---

### Solution

Your minimal code block can be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://google.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should remove the path from `webdriver.Chrome()` to solve the error as shown below. *This is recommended and you can see the answers of [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76915334/which-version-of-chrome-driver-does-webdriver-chrome-get-in-selenium-with-py) about which version of chrome driver `webdriver.Chrome()` gets:

```py
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://google.com/"
# path = "C:/Users/thefo/OneDrive/Desktop/summer 2023/chromedriver_win32"

driver = webdriver.Chrome() # Here
driver.get(url)
```

Or, you should set the path to [Service()](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html?) and set it to `webdriver.Chrome()` to solve the error as shown below:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://google.com/"
path = "C:/Users/thefo/OneDrive/Desktop/summer 2023/chromedriver_win32"

service = Service(executable_path=path) # Here
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service) # Here
driver.get(url)
```

Answer (score 0):

ref : https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/#use-with-chrome

## Install manager:

> pip install webdriver-manager

## Use with Chrome for selenium 4

```
   from selenium import webdriver
   from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
   from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

   driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).