# Selenium on Current Instance of Chrome

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

For context:

• Ventura 13.4.1

• Python 3.11.4

• Running in Jupyter Notebook in VSCode

• Selenium 4.11.2

I was able to run a Selenium script on an existing webpage, and then Selenium was unable to connect to Chrome because `WebDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain Selenium Manager` (not sure why it suddenly stopped working, no packages were updated).  I installed `Selenium 4.11.2` from miniconda, but [this bug report](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11234) said to try the `pip` release instead.

So then I couldn't connect to Chrome again.  `ChromeDriver` was installed by `brew` and `chromedriver --port=9222` says

```
Starting ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052}) on port 9222 
ChromeDriver was started successfully.
```

I also run `/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome -–remote-debugging-port=9222` and it opens a new Chrome window.

This is the beginning of my Selenium script:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pandas as pd
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
import json

chromeoptions = Options()
chromeoptions.debugger_address='127.0.0.1:9222'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager(driver_version='114.0.5735.90').install()), options=chromeoptions)
```

and it throws `Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:9222 from chrome not reachable`.

Both ChromeDriver and Google Chrome were added to my `PATH`

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/chromedriver/114.0.5735.90/chromedriver
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

as confirmed by `echo $PATH`: `/opt/homebrew/Caskroom/chromedriver/114.0.5735.90/chromedriver:/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome`

UPDATE:
Same error after

```
chromeoptions = Options()
chromeoptions.add_experimental_option(name='debuggerAddress', value='127.0.0.1:9222')
# chromeoptions.debugger_address='127.0.0.1:9222'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeoptions)
driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com")
```

, `./selenium-manager --browser chrome --debug` returns

```
DEBUG   Checking chromedriver in PATH
DEBUG   Running command: chromedriver --version
DEBUG   Output: "ChromeDriver 114.0.5735.90 (386bc09e8f4f2e025eddae123f36f6263096ae49-refs/branch-heads/5735@{#1052})"
DEBUG   Running command: which chromedriver
DEBUG   Output: "/opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver"
DEBUG   Found chromedriver 114.0.5735.90 in PATH: /opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver
DEBUG   chrome detected at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
DEBUG   Using shell command to find out chrome version
DEBUG   Running command: /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome --version
DEBUG   Output: "Google Chrome 114.0.5735.198 "
DEBUG   Detected browser: chrome 114.0.5735.198
DEBUG   Required driver: chromedriver 114.0.5735.90
INFO    Driver path: /opt/homebrew/bin/chromedriver
INFO    Browser path: /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
```

Comment: This might be a silly question, but have you tried closing and reopening the command prompt? Maybe reboot?

Comment: Tried both, also uninstalled Selenium multiple times, tried launching chromedriver and chrome in different orders.

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:9222 from chrome not reachable
```

...implies that *ChromeDriver* was unable to connect to the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) binary due to **incompatibility** issues.

---

### Solution with Selenium v4.6+ versions

As you are using *Selenium* ***v4.11.2*** you no more require to use [WebDriverManager](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63421086/7429447).

In such cases [*Selenium Manager*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76795080/7429447) can come to your rescue. [Selenium Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691426/7429447) which is now fully integrated with [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) can silently download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) in the background and execute the test.

So your effective code block can be:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

chromeoptions = Options()
chromeoptions.debugger_address='127.0.0.1:9222'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeoptions)
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant detailed discussions in:

- [[ Bug]: Selenium manager not found via Anaconda distribution](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/11234)
- [[ Bug]: Unable to obtain driver using Selenium Manager: C:\Users\mli86\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe is missing. Please open an issue on https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/12084)

Comment: I got the same error (in updated post), is it possible that `ChromeDriver` isn't communicating with `chrome`?  I should note that I'm trying to run the script on an already open webpage.