# Why can't chromedriver 117 support Chrome 117?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver

I'm trying to execute selenium to do some web scrapping. I'm trying to use the chrome & chromedriver 117, which are available for download [here](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/).

But when I try to execute the script, I get the following error:

```
ERROR - Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:38421

2023-08-03T15:14:09.917-03:00   from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114

2023-08-03T15:14:09.917-03:00   Current browser version is 117.0.5926.0
```

Why chromedriver only supports Chrome 114 if both are of version 117? And it's not exclusive for version 117, even if I use both of version 116 I get the same error.

Comment: That error message is telling you that the version of ChromeDriver being executed is *not* the version you think it is. Can you [edit] your question to include how you are initializing the driver? Also, try opening a command prompt and run `where chromedriver` for Windows operating systems, or `which chromedriver` for linux/Max OS. That should tell you where the driver exists in your PATH.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [selenium.common.exceptions.SessionNotCreatedException: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114. LATEST\_RELEASE\_115 doesn't exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76913935/selenium-common-exceptions-sessionnotcreatedexception-this-version-of-chromedri)

Answer (score 4):

This error message...

```
ERROR - Message: unknown error: cannot connect to chrome at 127.0.0.1:38421
2023-08-03T15:14:09.917-03:00   from session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 114
2023-08-03T15:14:09.917-03:00   Current browser version is 117.0.5926.0
```

...implies that [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) was unable to connect to the [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) binary due to **incompatibility** issues.

---

### Details

Though you are using *ChromeDriver* ***v114.0*** but your *Google Chrome* version is ***117.0***. Hence the incompatibility and the error.

---

### Solution with Selenium v4.6+ versions

In case you are using *Selenium* ***v4.6*** or above, in such cases [**Selenium Manager**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76795080/7429447) can become handy. [*Selenium Manager*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691426/7429447) is now fully integrated with *Selenium* and can silently download the matching [*ChromeDriver*](https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/) and you don't have to explicitly mention the *chromedriver* path anymore. So your minimal code block can be:

```
from selenium import webdriver

url = "https://google.com/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
```