# OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:60975/ error using SpecFlow in C# and ChromeDriver

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, specflow

Environment settings:

- Target Framework - 6
- Selenium.WebDriver.ChromeDriver -115.0.5790.17000
- Selenium.WebDriver - 4.11.0
- Chrome Version - 115.0.5790.171

I am trying to launch the chrome driver and getting below error:

```
Message: 
OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:60975/
```

Driver initialization code -

```
new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
driver = new ChromeDriver(); driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
```

Not sure how to resolve this issue?

Tried with different version of Selenium webdriver. Still getting same error.

Comment: show your driver initialization code...   have you checked that this port is not used?  (if you just let selenium choose the port, it'll find an available one...)

Comment: new WebDriverManager.DriverManager().SetUpDriver(new ChromeConfig());
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");                                                            How to let selenium choose port?

Comment: @Naveen Instead of comments edit the main question with this information.

Comment: not sure is new ChromeConfig() is needed there... maybe that's setting a default port?  I'd try it without.

Comment: I tried commenting out chromeconfig(). Still result is the same

Answer (score 1):

This error message...

```
Message:  OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverException : Cannot start the driver service on http://localhost:60975/
```

...indicates that Selenium was unable to start the *ChromeDriver* service.

---

### Solution with Selenium v4.10+ versions

You need to cross check if [*Selenium Manager*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76795080/7429447) is integrated within the current [specflow](/questions/tagged/specflow) *Test Framework* or in any of the later versions of the ***Specflow*** *Test Framework*.

[Selenium Manager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76691426/7429447) which is now fully integrated with [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54482491/7429447) ***v4.10*** and onwards, can silently download the matching [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59927747/7429447) in the background and execute the test and you won't require ***WebDriverManager*** any more.

So your effective code block can be:

```
driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("www.google.com");
```

Comment: We are already in Selenium 4.11 and it has been working fine for long time. It is causing issues from last 2 weeks. I am still struck with same issue.                                                                                                                   Note - I am able to start the Firfox browser , the problem is starting the Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided uses WebDriverManager to setup a ChromeDriver instance.
You may need to

- check the configuration that you set
- check if the WebDriverManager is downloading the driver properly

Instead of using WebDriverManager, you may try to create the service by referring to the chromedriver.exe in the Assembly path.

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Get Assembly path
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Full path to the assembly</returns>
    protected static string GetAssemblyPath()
    {
        var codeBase = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location ?? throw new Exception();
        var uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(codeBase);
        var path = Uri.UnescapeDataString(uriBuilder.Path);
        return Path.GetFullPath(path);
    }


    /// <inheritdoc/>
    protected override IWebDriver MakeLocalWebDriver()
    {
        var service = ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(Path.GetDirectoryName(GetAssemblyPath()));
        var driver = new ChromeDriver(service, ChromeOptions, CommandTimeout);
        return driver;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was to firewall that was implemented to our machine. Disabling the firewall fixed the issue. Thanks for the support.